# Getting T.class despite Java's type-erasure

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

I'm trying to bind an interface to its implementation as read from a configuration file so that I can feed it to my IoC container.  Here's roughly what I'm trying to do:

```
public class PropertyImplementationBinder<T> {
    // ...
    public Class getInterfaceClass() {
        return T.class; // OR Class<T>, note T is not newable
    }
    public Class getImplementationClass() {
        return /* read config file to get implementation class */;
    }
}
```

Is it somehow possible to get `T.class`?

Comment: [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1005283/1416458) seems more elegant

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to explicitly pass the class into the constructor (and store it yourself).

```
private final Class<T> clazz;

PropertyImplementationBinder(Class<T> clazz){
    this.clazz = clazz;
}

public Class<T> getInterfaceClass() {
    return clazz;
}
```

Comment: I think that should have been obvious to me... but it wasn't. Thank you!

Comment: The language could have done it for us, if it had been designed for it in version 1. It is a backwards compatibility thing. There was only so much that good be done by bolting this on to Java 5 without breaking old code.

Comment: Everyone look below; in many cases it *is* possible to do without passing in the class.

Answer (score 9):

You can get the actual type arguments for a generic superclass of a class. This [blog post](http://www.artima.com/forums/flat.jsp?forum=106&thread=208860) explores the possibilities presented by this, including a nice little trick using trivial anonymous inner classes. To quote directly:

> It turns out that while the JVM will not track the actual type arguments for instances of a generic class, it does track the actual type arguments for *subclasses* of generic classes. In other words, while a `new ArrayList<String>()` is really just a `new ArrayList()` at runtime, if a class extends `ArrayList<String>`, then the JVM knows that `String` is the actual type argument for `List`'s type parameter.

Comment: But then the developer knows as well since the class has a static T. It won't change at runtime.

Answer (score 5):

Contrary to what is widely accepted and rarely known type erasure can be avoided, which means that the callee do have the ability to know which generic parameters were employed during the call.

Please have a look at:
[Using TypeTokens to retrieve generic parameters](http://web.archive.org/web/20130731111227/http://www.jquantlib.org/index.php/Using_TypeTokens_to_retrieve_generic_parameters)

The article also talks about the experiences of our users with the technique. In a nutshell, we ended up falling back to the...

Conventional and widely used technique: *"Pass class types in constructors"*

Comment: well, that's creepy but amazing (let this be last fascination comment). i actually believe this should be the right answer with remark "you can also pass class in constructor"

Comment: Link appears to be broken... I know that Google's GSON library uses this approach, and I wanted to read an article on how it works

Comment: @ErinDrummond fixed with link to web.archive.org

Answer (score 1):

Btw. The example static method getType in article from @Richard Gomes  has two errors. it should go like this:

```
static public Class<?> getType(final Class<?> klass, final int pos) {
    // obtain anonymous, if any, class for 'this' instance
    final Type superclass = klass.getGenericSuperclass();

    // test if an anonymous class was employed during the call
    if ( !(superclass instanceof ParameterizedType) ) {
            throw new RuntimeException("This instance should belong to an anonymous class");
    }

    // obtain RTTI of all generic parameters
    final Type[] types = ((ParameterizedType) superclass).getActualTypeArguments();

    // test if enough generic parameters were passed
    if ( pos >= types.length ) {
            throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Could not find generic parameter #%d because only %d parameters were passed", pos, types.length));
    }

    if (!(types[pos] instanceof Class<?>)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Generic type is not a class but declaration definition(all you get is \"[T]\") " + types[pos]);
    }
    // return the type descriptor of the requested generic parameter
    return (Class<?>) types[pos];
}
```

Unfortunately it's still not the magic bullet because it works if you have in code explicitly

```
getType(new SomeObject<String>(){}.class, 0) // you get String.class
```

but if you call this on something like

```
getType(new SomeObject<T>(){}.class, 0) // you get T as TypeVariable<D> and not actuall class of it
```

Just name T.

Comment: In the second example, it may still be possible to find the actual type parameter for T, if the `TypeVariable.getGenericDeclaration()` is a Class.  It takes a lot of work to full the actual type arguments in any case (especially if they're defined by a superclass, there are multiple type parameters, etc. but I've written code to do it.

Answer (score -1):

No it's not possible.

The only exception to Java's type erasure is that via reflection you can find out the parameterized type via reflection on a class's fields.

Comment: No, you can also find parameterized type information from Class.getGeneric*(), and Method.getGeneric*().

Comment: It is possible see answers above.