# how to write T.class in java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to get class instance of generics type T](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437897/how-to-get-class-instance-of-generics-type-t)

Template's T
at

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(T.class);
```

can not compile T.class , do it need reflection and how?

```
    public void ConvertObjectToXML(String path, T bobject)
    {
        //Convert XML to Object
        File file = new File(path);
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(T.class);

        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        T customer2 = (T) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
        System.out.println(customer2);
    }
```

Comment: What is this 'T' reference ? It doesn't look like a generic (due to the T.class reference). How do you come by it ?

Comment: T is not a class, is it?

Comment: I'm guessing `T`is a generic type here? In that case the above code won't compile since `T.class` is not valid. This is due to type erasure. If you need the class of the generic in runtime, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225979/getting-t-class-despite-javas-type-erasure

Comment: yes, it is generic type, Template's T

Comment: Java generics are not the same as templates in C++; don't call T a "Template's T".

Comment: How to call ? i use XMLObj<Customer> XMLtool = new XMLObj<Customer>(customer); not success

Comment: @MartinLee: Don't put your own answer into the question. If you really want, you could answer your own question with the "updated solution"

Comment: in the past, someone told me to update solution in question, never mind , i deleted it

Comment: finally i use XMLObj<Customer> XMLtool = new XMLObj<Customer>(Customer.class);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the way Java handles generic types, this code cannot work:

```
public class Factory<T>{
   public T create(){
      return T.class.newInstance();
   }
}
```

You need to pass the actual generic type to the constructor (or any other method):

```
public class Factory<T>
   Class<T> c;
   publict Factory(Class<T> c){
       this.c=c;
   }
   public T create(){
       return c.newInstance();
   }
}
```

The classic way is to infer the generic type from an array as an array does hold its type:

```
public interface List<T>{
   ...
   T[] toArray(T[] target);
   ..
}
```

This is because the actual runtime type of `Factory<T>` is merely `Factory`, so the runtime has no access to its generic type.

Comment: how to call it? i use XMLObj<Customer> XMLtool = new XMLObj<Customer>(customer); not success

Comment: finally i use XMLObj<Customer> XMLtool = new XMLObj<Customer>(Customer.class);