# How do I get class type of generic list?

Tags: java, generics

I have this method

```
public <T> T PostQuery(String url, Object graph, Class<T> returnType)
```

and I want to call it like this

```
List<User> users = PostQuery("blabla", SomeObj, List<User>.class);
```

But I get error on the last argument. It allows me to only write `List.class`, which makes it a list of strings, not what I want.

How can I do that?

Comment: At runtime, you will only have `List`, so just send `List.class` as parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Due to Java implementation of generics (type erasure) there is no `List<User>.class` only `List.class`. So use either use just List.class or you can create a second method that already returns a list like this

```
public List<T> T PostQueryList(String url, Object graph, Class<T> returnType)
List<User> users = PostQueryList("blabla", SomeObj, User.class);
```

If you really need access to `List<User>` you might want to look into TypeTokens from Guava https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ReflectionExplained

Answer (score 0):

use only `User.class` as parameter

Answer (score 0):

According to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2226038/1264582
there is a workaround. Just use a subclass of your generic class.

Answer (score -1):

Use `public <T> T PostQuery(String url, Object graph){}` would be ok,because you have declared a generic type to this method when declare `<T>` like:

```
public <T> T PostQuery(String url, Object graph){
    Object obj = null;
    //...
    return (T)obj;
}
```

Comment: I use the result type inside the function