# How to get return type from any Method with Guava?

Tags: java, reflection, guava

What I understand from the [official Guava's `TypeToken` wiki](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ReflectionExplained#What%27s_the_return_type_of_List.get%28int%29_for_List%3CString&) is we can get the return type of a method even if it is defined by a [type argument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html#instantiation). But I cannot manage to retrieve the returned type of a [`Method`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html).

If I have an instanced `List<String>`, how can I do to get `String.class` from the `get()` method instead of `E`?

I know Java does type erasure during compile-time (i.e. the type argument is not available during runtime). Maybe I'm wrong, and Guava cannot retrieve the expected type of a method from a instanced class...

Answer (score 2):

If you can get a `TypeToken<List<String>>`, you can get the return type of its `get` method (as shown in the example). But if you have some arbitrary `List<?>` instance, you won't be able to get a `TypeToken` representing the actual type of that list (e.g. `List<String>`) because that information doesn't exist at runtime.

Comment: That String in `List<String>` shouldn't exists in runtime either - generic type erasure. How does guava solve it?

Comment: To get a `TypeToken<List<String>>`, you have to create a subclass of `TypeToken` with `new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}`.  Classes _do_ preserve generic type information, but individual objects don't.  `TypeToken` exploits that.

Comment: Alternatively, I suspect you could do something like what's described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225979/getting-t-class-despite-javas-type-erasure

Comment: In general, Guava solves it by having you get your `TypeToken` instance like this: `new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}`. This makes an anonymous subclass whose superclass is `TypeToken<List<String>>`. Since it's hardcoded into the superclass type at compile time, the `List<String>` info is available at runtime as well. Basically, there's a difference between generics in _classes_ and generics in _instances_ of classes.

Comment: @ChrisThompson: Indeed, one option (if someone else is passing the `List` to your code) is to require that a `TypeToken` for the type of the `List` also be passed in.

Answer (score -1):

As ColinD and Louis Wasserman have mentioned, generic type erasure does not erase generic type information about the super class. [Here](http://www.artima.com/forums/flat.jsp?forum=106&thread=208860) is also an interesting blog post about it.

The trick is to extend a class that declares generic type. This allows to use `getGenericSuperclass()` to retrieve generic type information.

```
private static class AnyClassWithGenerics<A, B, C> {
}

private static class SomeObject extends AnyClassWithGenerics<String, Number, ArrayList<Integer>> {
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Type genericSuperclass = SomeObject.class.getGenericSuperclass();

    if (genericSuperclass instanceof ParameterizedTypeImpl) {
        for (Type type : ((ParameterizedTypeImpl) genericSuperclass).getActualTypeArguments()) {
            System.out.println(type);
        }
    }
}
```

Above code produces this result:

```
class java.lang.String
class java.lang.Number
java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Integer>
```

The only ugly thing is that cast and I did not investigate under what conditions `getGenericSuperclass()` returns object of `ParameterizedTypeImpl` type.