# create Class reference of Generic class

Tags: java, generics

I want to create class reference for Generic class .

I am having a generic class called GenericRtt coded as below:

```
package com.practice.rtt;

public class GenericRtt<T> {

    private T s;


    public T getS() {
        return s;
    }


    public void setS(T s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

}
```

I want to create reference not instance of the class as . 

**Class <GenericRtt<String>> generics=(Class<GenericRtt<String>>) GenericRtt.class;**
I don't know how to create class reference of the GenericRtt.

Comment: What exactly would you be creating a reference to?

Comment: What exactly would you use this `generics` variable for?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The type of Class can only be the raw type.

The closest you can get is:

```
Class <GenericRtt> clazz = GenericRtt.class;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You should read about [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) in Java

also this might be very helpful [java-generic-class-determine-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004022/java-generic-class-determine-type)

Answer (score 0):

NO.

Even you have a reference ,Ultimately you have to create a object to use  the reference.

`GenericRtt rt = new GenericRtt();`

Then you can assign it or refer to some declared reference ,I guess.