# Java Generic type identification

Tags: java, generics

This is my class structure.

```
public class Node<T> {
    private T value;

    public Node(T val) {
        this.value = val;
    }

    public T evaluate() {
         return value;
    };

}
```

T can be `Integer`, `Double`, `Date`, `Long` or `String`.

Now, is there anyway I can get to know exactly what that type T is?  Thanks.

Comment: No, there is not.  The type parameter of any generic is removed at run time.  Look up Runtime Type Erasure for more information.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004022/java-generic-class-determine-type

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can invoke `getClass()` method **on** that *generic variable* and find out the class. Basically generics are erased at run-time, so an unbounded generic is nothing but `java.lang.Object`. So you can invoke all the method supported by `Object` class on that generic variable

At run-time, `getClass()` on generic object will return the actual `class` which was used to substitute the generic

For example

```
public class Node<T> {
    private T value;

    public Node(T val) {
        Class<?> clazz = val.getClass();
        checkType(clazz);
        this.value = val;
    }

    public T evaluate() {
         return value;
    };

    private void checkType(Class<?> c) {
       if(c.getName().equals(Integer.class.getName())) {
        //...
       }
    }

}
```

Comment: I didn't do that downvote. Thanks for your suggestion. Let me try that now.

Comment: @LPD The main point here being that if you have an actual instance of the class, you can identify it.  If you do not have an instance there is no way.

Comment: This is dangerous, e.g. you can get `Integer` as type parameter class, but it was actually instantiated as `Node<Number>`.

Answer (score 1):

Much easier, use `instanceof`.

```
public class Node<T> {
  private T value;

  public Node(T val) {
    checkType(val);
    this.value = val;
  }

  public T evaluate() {
     return value;
  };

  private void checkType(T val) {
    if(val instanceof Integer) {
      //...
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Though there is already an accepted answer, I think it may be good to add one more answer:

As mentioned by @BaileyS, there is no way to get info of T in a place without an instance of T.

The solution greatly depends on why you want T, how you are using it.  Normally, if we need the type of T for the logic (e.g. creating a new instance of T), it is usually done by providing the `Class` instance.

For example, you can make your Node class be:

```
public class Node<T> {
    private T value;
    private Class<T> valueType;

    public Node(T val, Class<T> valueType) {
        this.value = val;
        this.valueType = valueType;
    }
    //.....    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you know that your node will store only Number you could restrict it.

```
public class Node<T extends Number> {

    private final T value;

    public Node(T val) {
        this.value = val;
    }

    public T evaluate() {
         return value;
    };

    public Class<? extends Number> type() { 
      return value.getClass();
    }       

}
```