# Using parameterized type to determine type

Tags: java, generics

I was going throught this link

[Java Generic Class - Determine Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004022/java-generic-class-determine-type)

I tried with this program.

```
package my;

import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public class GenericTypeIdentification {

    public static void main( String args[] ) {
        Node<Integer> obj = new GenericTypeIdentification().new SubNode<Integer>( 1 );
        ParameterizedType parameterizedType = ( ParameterizedType ) obj.getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        Type clazz = parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        if ( clazz == Integer.class ) {
            System.out.println( 1 );
        }
        else {
            System.out.println( 2 );
        }
    }

    class Node<T> {

        private final T value;

        public Node( T val ) {
            this.value = val;
        }

        public T evaluate() {
            return value;
        };

    }

    class SubNode<T> extends Node<T> {

        private final T value;

        public SubNode( T val ) {
            super( val );
            value = val;
        }

        @Override
        public T evaluate() {
            return value;
        };
    }
}
```

My understanding was that it should printh output as `1` but it prints `2`. Please help me in understanding this. Thanks.

Comment: Due to type erasure, you can't determine the generic type at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A trick that actually works is used in the [google guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice)'s [TypeLiteral](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/source/browse/core/src/com/google/inject/TypeLiteral.java). In the constructor of a *subclass* of a generic class, you *do* have access to the parent's generic "instantiation", even at runtime... because the generic type information has been retained for inheritance purposes at compile-time. Example usage:

```
TypeLiteral<MyClass> test = new TypeLiteral<MyClass>() {}; // notice the {} to build an anon. subclass
System.err.println(test.getType()); // outputs "MyClass"
```

This does not work without using a subclass-of-a-generic, due to type erasure; and is probably overkill for most applications.

Comment: Interesting, I thought the information is completely lost at runtime!

Answer (score 1):

Clazz would be T in this case.

Generics are considered only at compile time in java. You can attempt to determine the value of the type parameter of a collection at runtime by looking at its members' classes(without 100% certainty, you can end up with a subclass...). There is no way to determine the type parameter value of an empty collection at runtime.

Comment: True in the general case, but false when class hierarchies are involved - see my answer above :-)