# Java compare generic type with Void

Tags: java, generics, types, void

I have problem with comparing java generic type if it is type of Void or not. In other words I'm trying to ensure if my generic type T is Void or not. 
My sample implementation:

```
public abstract class Request<T>{

     private T member;

     protected void comparing(){
         if(T instanceof Void) // this make error "Expression expected"
             runAnotherMethod();

         //if I type
         if(member instanceof Void) //Incovertible types; cannot cast T to java.lang.Void
             runAnotherMethod();
     }

     protected void runAnotherMethod(){...}
}

public class ParticularRequest extends Request<Void>{
}
```

I've tried to compare id via `instanceof`, `Class<T>` and `Class<Void>`, `T.class` and `Void.class`.
But the AndroidStudio show me error in every tried case :(

can you help me how to compare it?
thanks.

Comment: What errors are you getting? They may explain why each approach is not working...

Comment: I'm not sure what is the purpose of that code, but Void is a uninstanciable class, so that intanceof will always return false

Comment: I would like to use it in order to ensure more detailed generic type in child classes of Request. I use it in other methods of parent and child classes

Answer (score 2):

When using java generics you often need to ask for the class of the generic type in the constructor so that you can actually work with the class. I guess, that is a confusing sentence so just see the example below:

```
public abstract class Request<T> {

    private Class<T> clazz;

    // constructor that asks for the class of the generic type
    public Request(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    // helper function involving the class of the generic type.
    // in this case we check if the generic type is of class java.lang.Void
    protected boolean isVoidRequest(){
        return clazz.equals(Void.class);
    }

    // functionality that depends on the generic type
    protected void comparing() {
        if (isVoidRequest()) {
            runAnotherMethod();
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

When you subclass you must pass the class of the generic type to the super constructor.

```
public class LongRequest extends Request<Long> {
    public LongRequest() {
        super(Long.class);
    }
}

public class VoidRequest extends Request<Void> {
    public VoidRequest() {
        super(Void.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store a `private` member that is of the generic type of the class.

```
public abstract class Request<T> {

     private T memberOfGenericType;

     protected void comparing() {
         if (memberOfGenericType instanceof Sometype)
             runAnotherMethod();
     }

     protected void runAnotherMethod() { ... }

     public T getMemberOfGenericType() {
        return memberOfGenericType;
     }

     public void setMemberOfGenericType(T value) {
        this.memberOfGenericType = value;
     }
}
```

This way, at Runtime, the `memberOfGenericType` will have the type of `Sometype` and you will be able to **compile** the `if` statement. You can also verify that the `memberOfGenericType` is `Sometype` at Runtime, by using the getter I've added.

Anyhow, **as a side note**, I would say that there's no need of generic type, if you don't use it as a type for a member, method or method parameter and then you should re-consider your design. Also, in particular, the type `Void` is not instantiable, so you wouldn't be able to pass a valid instance for the class member, which more or less makes the `if` statement useless.

Comment: If I do it like your exmaple so it get me error on the line:
    if(member instanceof Void) //Incovertible types; cannot cast T to java.lang.Void

Comment: I don't get any **compilation** errors. Are you sure you haven't mixed up something?

Comment: The "if" will always return false, because (null instanceof Anything) is false, by the definition of instanceof: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950319/is-null-check-needed-before-calling-instanceof

Comment: @kocko -- but that makes your answer a non-answer: "you can do it like this" + "it is always wrong to do it like this" == "do not do this"

Answer (score 0):

You can't use T like that.  You need some instance to compare.  For example some member or parameter:

```
public abstract class Request<T> {
    T member;

     protected void comparing(T param){
         if(member instanceof Void)
             runAnotherMethod();

         if(param instanceof Void)
             runAnotherMethod();

     }

     protected void runAnotherMethod(){...}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach to accessing the parameter class, used by [Guice](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/TypeLiteral.html), is to use the fact that, while a generic class cannot access its own 'class' arguments, its subclasses **do** have access to these arguments: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/18610693/15472

If you need this, either use Guice' `TypeLiterals`, or reimplment their logic.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are no objects that are instances of the `Void` type in Java you can't use `instanceof` here.

`null` is the only value that is a member of the type `Void`. So maybe what you want to do is this?:

```
 if (memberOfGenericType == null)
     runAnotherMethod();
```

### About the type `Void`

No objects of type `Void` can be created because the class only has a private constructor and it is never invoked from within the class. `Void` is usually used in these situations:

- To get a `Class` object that represents the return type of methods declared to return `void`.
- As a placeholder type argument, when the fields and variables of that type are not meant to be used.

Answer (score 0):

At run-time `T` is compiled as `Object`, and the actual class is unknown. As others said, you should maintain an instance of your parametrized type, but this is not automatic: You need to instantiate it, and the constructor `T()` cannot be used.

Also `java.lang.Void` cannot be instantiated, so you should use another class, like a self-made `Void` class.

Try something like this:

```
public final class Void {}; // cannot use java.lang.Void, so create another class...

public abstract class Request<T> {
  protected abstract T member(); // A member would need to be initialized...

  protected void comparing(T param){
    if(member() instanceof Void) // Use our Void not java.lang.Void
      runAnotherMethod();

  }

  protected void runAnotherMethod(){...}
}

public class ParticularRequest extends Request<Void>{
  @Override
  protected Void member() { return new Void(); } // Could be optimized...
}
```

---

Edit:

I do not see, why would you need this, however.
If you have different children for different types, then you also could have different implementations, too.

Something like this (types and methods are for example only):

```
public abstract class Request<T> {
  protected abstract T method();
}

public class RequestInt extends Request<Integer> {
  @Override
  protected Integer method() {...}
}

public class RequestText extends Request<String> {
  @Override
  protected String method() {...}
}
```