# different ways of checking the type of an object in java?

Tags: java, object

I have an object **obj** and a class name **MyClass**, i can check whether obj is of the type MyClass using either instanceof or i can say obj.getClass().equals("MyClass").
So i want to know are there any other ways of checking the type of an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beware: `instanceof` returns true also if your object is a subclass of `MyClass` , or if it implements the interface  (this is usually what you are interested in - if you recall the "IS A" OOP concept)

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496928/what-is-the-difference-between-instanceof-and-class-isassignablefrom) about  `Class.isAssignableFrom()`, similar to `instanceof` but a little more powerful.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the two options you cite are *not* equivalent:

```
"foo" instanceof Comparable // returns true
"foo".getClass().equals(Comparable.class) // return false
```

Answer (score 1):

[Class#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)) is another option.

Answer (score 0):

instanceof is another option.

Answer (score 0):

`instancef` is not proper solution as it gives true for subclass of a class. Use this instead:

```
 obj.getClass().equals("MyClass")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably recurse through `obj.getClass().getSuperClass()` to get something similar to `instanceof`.

Answer (score 0):

As said by others, `instanceof` does not have the same functionality as `equals`.

On another point, when dealing with this problem in code, using a [Visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)-pattern is a clean (although not smallest in lines of code) solution. A nice advantage is that once a visitor-interface has been setup for a set of classes, this can be reused again in all other places that need to handle all/some/one different extensions of a class.