# java: Class.isInstance vs Class.isAssignableFrom

Tags: java

Let `clazz` be some `Class` and `obj` be some `Object`.

Is

```
clazz.isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass())
```

always the same as

```
clazz.isInstance(obj)
```

?

If not, what are the differences?

Comment: if obj == null, the second returns false, the first does not. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey, the first will throw a `NullPointerException` if `obj == null`.

Comment: Found some answer with samples from hrere : http://www.mytechnotes.biz/2012/07/java-instanceof-isassignablefrom-or.html

Comment: To the readers: you are about to enter a deep, dark, black hole from which you will never escape. The differences are endless. Give up now while you still can: https://stackoverflow.com/q/496928/1599699

Comment: @ParameshKorrakuti the domain name is changing to https://tshikatshikaaa.blogspot.com/2012/07/java-instanceof-isassignablefrom-or.html

Answer (score 252, accepted):

`clazz.isAssignableFrom(Foo.class)` will be true whenever the class represented by the `clazz` object is a superclass or superinterface of `Foo`.

`clazz.isInstance(obj)` will be true whenever the object `obj` is an instance of the class `clazz`.

That is:

```
clazz.isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass()) == clazz.isInstance(obj)
```

is always true so long as `clazz` and `obj` are nonnull.

Comment: this misses the case where the Foo is the same as clazz - in which case it returns true: Pauls top-voted answer below corrects this

Comment: I agree that when clazz is a Foo, then clazz.isAssignableFrom(Foo.class) is true. Where did I say otherwise?

Comment: This isn't 100% true. `Comparable.class.isAssignableFrom(Byte.class) == true` but `Byte.class.isInstance(Comparable.class) == false`. In other words, `isInstance()` is not symmetric for interfaces, only for subclasses.

Comment: @Gili This isn't what uckelman said. Please re-read his answer.

Comment: `Byte b = 3;
Comparable.class.isAssignableFrom(b.getClass()) == Comparable.class.isInstance(b));`
 -> it's true also for interfaces.

Comment: Technicality: If `obj` is `null` then `clazz.isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass()) == clazz.isInstance(obj)` will throw a `NullPointerException` and not return `true`.

Answer (score 209):

Both answers are in the ballpark but neither is a complete answer.

`MyClass.class.isInstance(obj)` is for checking an instance.  It returns true when the parameter obj is non-null and can be cast to `MyClass` without raising a `ClassCastException`.  In other words, obj is an instance of `MyClass` or its subclasses.

`MyClass.class.isAssignableFrom(Other.class)` will return true if `MyClass` is the same as, or a superclass or superinterface of, `Other`.  `Other` can be a class or an interface.  It answers true if `Other` can be converted to a `MyClass`.

A little code to demonstrate:

```
public class NewMain
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        NewMain nm = new NewMain();
        nm.doit();
    }

    class A { }

    class B extends A { }

    public void doit()
    {
        A myA = new A();
        B myB = new B();
        A[] aArr = new A[0];
        B[] bArr = new B[0];

        System.out.println("b instanceof a: " + (myB instanceof A)); // true
        System.out.println("b isInstance a: " + A.class.isInstance(myB)); //true
        System.out.println("a isInstance b: " + B.class.isInstance(myA)); //false
        System.out.println("b isAssignableFrom a: " + A.class.isAssignableFrom(B.class)); //true
        System.out.println("a isAssignableFrom b: " + B.class.isAssignableFrom(A.class)); //false
        System.out.println("bArr isInstance A: " + A.class.isInstance(bArr)); //false
        System.out.println("bArr isInstance aArr: " + aArr.getClass().isInstance(bArr)); //true
        System.out.println("bArr isAssignableFrom aArr: " + aArr.getClass().isAssignableFrom(bArr.getClass())); //true
    }
}
```

Comment: The 3rd-to-last and 2nd-to-last lines both say `bArr isInstance aArr` but the code is different.

Comment: Why in your example "b isAssignableFrom a:" but code is `A.class.isAssignableFrom(B.class)`? I confused by output :)

Comment: MyClass.class.isInstance(obj) will also work for interfaces:
_If this Class object represents an interface, this method returns true if the class or any superclass of the specified Object argument implements this interface._

Comment: ummm... in all your examples "instanceOf" returns true iff "isAssignableFrom" returns true... I don't see the difference this way.

Comment: System.out.println("b isAssignableFrom a: " + A.class.isAssignableFrom(B.class));
        System.out.println("a isAssignableFrom b: " + B.class.isAssignableFrom(A.class)); should be

System.out.println("b isAssignableFrom a: " + B.class.isAssignableFrom(A.class));
        System.out.println("a isAssignableFrom b: " + A.class.isAssignableFrom(B.class));

Comment: This doesn't answer the question whether `clazz.isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass()) == clazz.isInstance(obj)` is true for all `obj != null`.

Comment: Be careful the text printed out doesn't match the code and can be confusing ...    Example:    "System.out.println("b isAssignableFrom a: " + A.class.isAssignableFrom(B.class));"

Comment: This fails to answer the question, namely, "what are the differences?" Everyone here has (hopefully) read the javadoc. What we need is some analysis.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky, what differences or analysis areyou looking for?

Comment: @Paul The answer, as is, is not helpful, because the reader is left wondering "what is the difference between an object being an instance of a subclass of a class and the object's type being convertible to the class?" Surely, you can see that you've left the reader with as many questions after reading your answer as he had when arriving at this page. A better answer would actually explain the difference (or lack thereof). If there is no difference, the answer should directly state, "there is no practical difference."

Comment: More importantly, the reader is left wondering what the heck to use for their purposes. According to the comments in the question, `isAssignableFrom()` throws a `NullPointerException` if the object is null, whereas `isInstance()` just returns false. That's the real answer.

Answer (score 10):

I think the result for those two should always be the same. The difference is that you need an instance of the class to use `isInstance` but just the `Class` object to use `isAssignableFrom`.

Comment: This isn't 100% true. `Comparable.class.isAssignableFrom(Byte.class) == true` but `Byte.class.isInstance(Comparable.class) == false`. In other words, `isInstance()` is not symmetric for interfaces, only for subclasses.

Comment: @Gili: You've got it a bit wrong there. `Byte.class.isInstance(Comparable.class)` is false because a `Class` object is not an instance of `Byte`. The correct comparison to `Comparable.class.isAssignableFrom(Byte.class)` is `Comparable.class.isInstance((byte) 1)`, which is true.

Comment: I disagree. If you look up the Javadoc of `Byte` you will discover it extends `Number` and is a class. `(byte) 1` is not equivalent to `Byte`. The former is a primitive. The latter is a Class.

Comment: @Gili: Autoboxing casts primitive `byte` to `Byte` because the parameter type of `isInstance` is `Object`.

Comment: Okay. My original point was that the calls are not exactly symmetric to each other, but having re-read your answer you never made this assertion so you're right.

Answer (score 8):

For brevity, we can understand these two APIs like below:

1. `X.class.isAssignableFrom(Y.class)`

If `X` and `Y` are the same class, or `X` is `Y`'s super class or super interface, return true, otherwise, false.

2. `X.class.isInstance(y)`

Say `y` is an instance of class `Y`, if `X` and `Y` are the same class, or `X` is `Y`'s super class or super interface, return true, otherwise, false.

Comment: So you are saying isAssignableFrom takes class and isInstance takes instance. That is the only difference?