# Class#isInstance vs Class#isAssignableFrom

Tags: java, class, instance

Given a `Class<?> superType` and a `Object subInstance`, what are the differences between

```java
superType.isInstance(subInstance)
```

and

```java
superType.isAssignableFrom(subInstance.getClass())
```

(if any)?

Comment: check out the java source code

Comment: @Sunny Both methods are native.

Comment: oops!! didn't thought about it

Comment: Perhaps you could take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949260/java-class-isinstance-vs-class-isassignablefrom)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`isAssignableFrom` also tests whether the type can be converted via an identity conversion or via a widening reference conversion.

```
    Class<?> cInt = Integer.TYPE;

    Long l = new Long(123);

    System.out.println(cInt.isInstance(l)); // false
    System.out.println(cInt.isAssignableFrom(cInt)); // true
```

Comment: The sample code seems to be proving nothing -- `cInt.isAssignableFrom(cInt)` is of course true, since it's testing itself.  This is not a comparison to `cInt.isInstance(l)`, because `l` is a Long, not `Integer.TYPE`.

Answer (score 4):

In the scenario, there is no difference.

The difference between both methods are the parameters. One works with object and one with classes:

[Class#isInstance(Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29)

> Determines if the specified Object is assignment-compatible
>   with the object represented by this Class.

[Class#isAssignableFrom(Class)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29)

> Determines if the class or interface represented by this
>   Class object is either the same as, or is a superclass or
>   superinterface of, the class or interface represented by the specified
>   Class parameter.

Answer (score 1):

`isAssignableFrom()` will be true whenever the class represented by the class object is a superclass or superinterface of `subInstance.getClass()`

`isInstance()` will be true whenever the object `subInstance` is an instance of `superType`.

So the basic difference is that `isInstance` works with instances `isAssignableFrom` works with classes.

I often use `isAssignableFrom` if I don't have an instance/don't want to instantiate the class for some reason. Otherwise you can use both.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html):

```
isInstance(Object obj)
Determines if the specified Object is assignment-compatible with the object represented by this Class.

isAssignableFrom(Class<?> cls)
Determines if the class or interface represented by this Class object is either the same as, or is a superclass or superinterface of, the class or interface represented by the specified Class parameter.
```

So it sounds like the two methods do very similar things, but one takes an `Object` and looks at the `Class` of that object, while the other one takes a `Class`.