# Pass classname to method

Tags: java, instanceof

My programs tend to use a lot of wrapped exceptions (`SwingWorker`, for instance, wraps all its exceptions in `ExecutionException`). So, I am trying to write a method that will allow me to check if an exception or any of its causes is an `instanceof` an exception type, but I don't know how (if it is even possible) to pass JUST a class name as an argument to a method.

So far, I have this:

```
public static boolean errorOrCausesInstanceOfClass(Throwable e, Class c) {
    return e != null && (e.getClass().equals(c) || (e.getCause() != null && errorOrCausesInstanceOfClass(e.getCause(), c)));
}
```

But this will only work if `e.getClass()` is exactly equal to `c.getClass()`. But I'd like to check using `instanceof` to catch subclasses as well.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Class is a raw type and should be parameterized on your method like    (Throwable e, Class<?> c)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try use

```
Class.isAssignableFrom(Class clazz)
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)

Answer (score 4):

Look at `Class.isAssignableFrom()`.

Answer (score 1):

See the handy method `Class.isInstance()`

```
    if( ... c.isInstance(e) ...
```

Comment: I prefer this solution to `Class.isAssignableFrom()`

Comment: @MikeB, is there any particular reason why? Even after reading this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949260/java-class-isinstance-vs-class-isassignablefrom) I am still having trouble understanding why one is preferable over the other

Comment: @ryvantage, it's mainly a personal preference. The only real advantage that I'm aware of is you don't have to worry about a NullPointerException.

Comment: @MikeB, I think then you have the wrong preference. Because with `isAssignableFrom` you have to invoke the `getClass()` method of your parameter, which throws a NPE if it is null. `isInstance` is the method that won't throw a NPE.

Comment: @ryvantage Yes, I said I preferred this solution (the one in the answer this comment is below), which is `c.isInstance(e)` for exactly the reason you point out.

Comment: Ahhhhhh haha sorry I didn't see the "to". :) I thought you were saying you prefer `isAssignableFrom()`. Sorry. :)