# Compare object with class stored in field

Tags: java, class

I am trying to compare `part` with the `c` class given from the constructor but for some reason my IDE pops a warning that it will always be false.

```
Class<? extends Part> c;

public Slot(Class<? extends Part> c){
    this.c = c;
}

public boolean addItem(Part part){
    return part instanceof c;
}
```

Why is this instanceof statement always false and what is the correct syntax to compare `part` with `c`?

Comment: `c` is not `Part` but `Class<Part>` so `Part` != `Class<Part>`

Comment: @gtgaxiola and what would be the correct syntax to compare `part` with a class saved in a field?

Comment: @Fabien Fleureau already answered

Comment: @Nick - now your question does not make sense! You changed the code so it does not match your text below. Please return it back so the question remains consistent.

Comment: @HonzaZidek oops sorry updated the code to fix the `extends Part` part  and forgot I was trying out the code from one from the answers, fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this

```
if(part instanceof c) return true;
```

Try this

```
if(c.isAssignableFrom(part.getClass())) return true;
```

This is [different than `Class.isInstance(Object)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949260/java-class-isinstance-vs-class-isassignablefrom), because [`isAssignableFrom`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)) also returns true when `part` is the same type as *or* a sub-class of `c`.

So if you need to know if this is the *exact same type* use `isInstance`, if it could also be a sub-class, then use `isAssignableFrom`.

Comment: Wont work I need to supply a subclass of `Part` in the constructor as you see in the code and this if statement to check if its the same subclass.

Comment: Oh. c is a *class*. I didn't catch that.

Comment: its `classObject.isAssignableFrom` not `object`. so it would be `c.isAssignableFrom(part.getClass())` if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 8):

You should call the following Class method:

[Class.isInstance(Object obj)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29)

When you call "instanceof c", "c" should be a Class, not a variable. In your example, c is a variable whose type is Class.

Answer (score 1):

It's about understanding the operator `instanceof` and the `Class` class.

Type Comparison Operator [instanceof](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2):

> At run time, the result of the `instanceof` operator is `true` if the
>   value of the `RelationalExpression` is not `null` and the reference could
>   be cast to the `ReferenceType` without raising a `ClassCastException`.
>   Otherwise the result is `false`.

This means that your code `if (part instanceof c) ...` will always return false, as `part` can never be cast to `Class`.

If you have a look at [Class.inInstance(Object obj)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance-java.lang.Object-), you find that

> This method is the dynamic equivalent of the Java language `instanceof` operator.

In other words:

1. If you know the checked type in compile-time, you use `instanceof`.
2. If you do not know the checked type in compile-time, but in run-time (so you have it stored in a variable of the `Class` type), you use `Class.inInstance(Object obj)`.