# How to cast a String to my own class?

Tags: java

I want to know how to cast a String into my own class the way org.json.JSONObject does.

You can cast the String: {"key":"value"} as a JSONObject even though JSONObject inherits only from Object.

How do i get a String to cast as a MyOwnClassObject while only inheriting from Object?

Comment: some generics magic i guess. certainly doable whatcha got thus far?

Comment: What you're asking is not possible. Casting rules aren't negotiable: the candidate variable must be [assignable from](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949260/java-class-isinstance-vs-class-isassignablefrom) the target type. If not, your code will not compile. And if the cast type is not assignable from the runtime type of the candidate variable, the result is a `ClassCastException`. References [Assignment Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2) and [Casting Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5).

Answer (score 6):

`new JSONObject(str)` is not a cast, it is just a normal constructor.

If you want to implement such a thing, just define a constructor for your class that takes a single `String`.

Comment: [JSONObject(String) constructor documentation](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject(java.lang.String))