# Type-safe way to cast object to Class

Tags: java, casting, type-conversion

I want to remove the suppression of the unchecked conversion warning.  How can I cast `o` to `T` with complete surety?

Of note: the ResultSet in this snippet is a proprietary wrapper that is source-agnostic.  It's very similar to java.sql.ResultSet, but it is not the same.  Also, using Eclipse Mars.1 with Java 8 u45, and both the IDE and javac issue the warning.  I realize that since it's wrapped in that `if` statement, that it's technically not an issue, but I absolutely hate to suppress warnings.  And I feel like there's gotta be a completely type-safe way to perform that conversion.

```
public class ResultSetQuery {
    public static <T> List<T> collectValues(ResultSet rs, String keyName, Class<T> tclass) {

        List<T> result = new LinkedList<>();

        while(rs.next()) {
            Object o = rs.getData(keyName);

            if (tclass.isAssignableFrom(o.getClass())) {

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                T v = (T)o;

                result.add(v);
            } else {
                result.add(null);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you bother? The test `isAssignableFrom` makes sure that the cast cannot fail, so in theory the compiler could be smart enough to not issue the warning, but anyway it is safe to suppress the warning.

Comment: Is the ResultSet from `java.sql` package? I didn't find the `getData` method in the official documentation.

Comment: `while (rs.next())` can throw an `SQLException`, so you need to either declare a `throws SQLException` in the method, or surround the `while` code with a `try-catch`. --- `rs.getData(keyName)` is a `java.sql.ResultSet`, right? Verify if the `.getData(String)` method exists; because looks like it doesn't. Maybe you meant *getDat**e***?

Comment: @wero I don't know about other compilers, but the JDK's, used by NetBeans (8), ***is*** smart enough to not issue a warning. =)

Comment: @AlmightyR interesting. I tried with `javac` from JDK 8 but it complains. Doesn't NetBean use `javac`?.

Comment: @wero AFAIK it uses `javac` from JDK, but it's not complaining here. Maybe you have an older version? I have `8u66` (`1.8.0_45-b15`) here.

Comment: @phillipe, sorry, i forgot to annotate that - that ResultSet is proprietary, and unfortunately, it's named the same as java.sql's ResultSet :/  it acts very similarly to java.sql.ResultSet, but is source agnostic, which is why it exists

Comment: @wero, i understand that, but using Mars.1 and the latest build of Java 8, i am getting warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write:

```
            if (tclass.isAssignableFrom(o.getClass())) {
                result.add(tclass.cast(o));
            }
```

(See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast(java.lang.Object).)

---

**Edited to add:** Incidentally, as erickson points out in a comment, you should probably be writing `tclass.isInstance(o)` instead of `tclass.isAssignableFrom(o.getClass())`: it's simpler and clearer, and it avoids a NullPointerException when `o` is null.

Comment: that removes the warning and also accomplishes what i set out to do.  so simple!

Comment: @liltitus27: your comment makes me sad. you now have 2 native method calls instead of 1, and the cast is still there inside Class#cast. Out of sight, out of mind I guess.

Comment: @wero why does that make you sad? :( i don't wanna make anyone sad.  you yourself said that `Class#cast` does what I'm doing, so why not delegate the warning suppression to `java.lang.Class`?  as long as i keep that call inside the `isAssignableFrom` check, i'm okay, right?  or is your point that any future dev doesn't see this suppressed warning, and so isn't obviously aware that this is occurring?

Comment: oh, and i suppose i'm duplicating checks this way, too, since `Class#cast`'s code performs safety checks that i've already determined are not needed.

Comment: This is a good solution. It will prevent class casting errors in locations where no explicit cast occurs (like where items are consumed from the list). It's not an unsafe cast, like `add((T) o)` would be. Use `isInstance()` instead of `isAssignableFrom()`, though.

Comment: @erickson, are you sure?  looking at http://stackoverflow.com/a/6983596/1322243, it seems to me that i would want to keep it using `isAssignableFrom`.  what's your reasoning for not using that method?

Comment: @liltitus27 Really? Why? I don't see anything in that answer to support your use of `isAssignableFrom()`. You have an object. You want to test whether it's an instance of a particular type. That's precisely the function of `isInstance()`. `isAssignableFrom()` is a roundabout way of doing the same thing, and that roundabout includes the possibility of a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @erickson...whoa, did my asking a question on stackoverflow just piss you off?  `isInstance` won't return `true` for superclasses or interfaces for which Class is applicable.  which is why i chose to use `isAssignableFrom`

Comment: additionally, i don't have an instance of `T`, i have a `Class` of type `T`

Comment: @liltitus27: I don't think you've "pissed [erickson] off". I read his/her comment as expressing confusion rather than anger. (FWIW, I share that confusion. The answer that you've linked to explains that this use-case is the exact purpose of `isInstance`, and I don't see how you can be interpreting it differently.)

Comment: @ruakh, ok, guess i got a lil defensive there, my bad.  i'm having trouble understanding the difference between the two.  i've read the javadocs, and the linked article, but evidently, i'm not discerning that difference adequately.

Comment: @liltitus27: I've updated my answer to explain how you'd use `isInstance` -- hopefully that clarifies.

Comment: @liltitus27 Yes, ruakh is right, I was not mad, just bewildered. The linked answer's passage, "... `obj` is an instance of `MyClass` or its subclasses..." means that `obj` "is-a" `MyClass`---it's either `MyClass` or something that implements or extends `MyClass`. In statically typed code you'd want to write: `if (o instanceof T) result.add((T) o);`, right? The `isInstance()` method is the reflective equivalent: it *will* return `true` when the target `Class` is an interface implemented by the argument, or is a super class of the argument.

Comment: @erickson thanks for the explanation and kinda spelling it out for me, sometimes it takes a minute for things to click.

Answer (score 3):

Your intention to not blindly silence compiler warnings is honorable but your code example is a good example for a justified use of `@SupressWarnings`. Your code cannot fail, and still the compiler complains, therefore `@SupressWarnings` is the way to go.

Take a look at `java.lang.Class#cast` which has the same pattern as your example. It also suppresses the warning:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public T cast(Object obj) {
    if (obj != null && !isInstance(obj))
        throw new ClassCastException(cannotCastMsg(obj));
    return (T) obj;
}
```

Comment: ok, that's what i expected. figured i'd see if the community knew of a way to handle that without suppression of the warning, but your example makes it fairly obvious that this approach is okay.  thanks for the input!