# Check if an exception instance is present in a generics array

Tags: java, arrays

I want to check if an instance of a particular exception is present in a generics array. (I expect all elements of the array are to be some exceptions.)

Here's what I have tried:

```
class Ideone
{
    public static boolean isPresent(final Throwable t, final Class<?>[] exceptionArray){
        for(Class<?> exc : exceptionArray){
            if(t instanceof exc.getClass() ){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // your code goes here
        Class<?>[] my = {RuntimeException.class};
        isPresent(RuntimeException.class, my);
    }
}
```

Here's an [IDEOne link](https://ideone.com/wB8Hrp) if that helps you to simulate. 
Here, I get the error `expected )`

On IntelliJ Idea, on hovering, I get the error `cannot resolve symbol 'getClass'`.

Any Ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code if you want to check the instance:

```
class Ideone {
    public static boolean isPresent(final Throwable t, final Class<?>[] exceptionArray) {
        for (Class<?> exc : exceptionArray) {
            if (exc.isAssignableFrom(t.getClass())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        // your code goes here
        Class<?>[] my = { RuntimeException.class };
        System.out.println("RuntimeException: " + isPresent(new RuntimeException(), my));
        System.out.println("IllegalStateException: " + isPresent(new IllegalStateException(), my));
        System.out.println("NoSuchMethodException: " + isPresent(new NoSuchMethodException(), my));
    }
}
```

Results in:

> RuntimeException: true 
>   IllegalStateException: true
>   NoSuchMethodException: false

Or this code if you want to check if the exception class matches:

```
class Ideone {
    public static boolean isPresent(final Throwable t, final Class<?>[] exceptionArray) {
        for (Class<?> exc : exceptionArray) {
            if (exc.equals(t.getClass())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        // your code goes here
        Class<?>[] my = { RuntimeException.class };
        System.out.println("RuntimeException: " + isPresent(new RuntimeException(), my));
        System.out.println("IllegalStateException: " + isPresent(new IllegalStateException(), my));
        System.out.println("NoSuchMethodException: " + isPresent(new NoSuchMethodException(), my));
    }
}
```

Results in:

> RuntimeException: true
>   IllegalStateException: false
>   NoSuchMethodException: false

First mistake was passing `RuntimeException.class` instead of an instance `new RuntimeException()`. 
Second, `exc` is already a class object you don't need `exc.getClass()`.
Third you did't not return false in case it did not find the exception.

Comment: Thanks. This looks good. Please add this link in the answer to help future visitors to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949260/java-class-isinstance-vs-class-isassignablefrom

Comment: sorry was still working on the answer, now has two options.

Comment: The new one is better. The downsides of `isAssignableFrom` is that it will match all super classes.

Answer (score 1):

you should change the variable `t` to represent a `Class` inheriting from `Throwable`. Your current implementation requires you to pass an instance of `Throwable` to the function, which is quite unnecessary if you want to check if a specific Exception is present. By changing it to `Class<? extends Throwable>` you can simply pass `Exception.class` and further on you just check if `exc` is assignable from `t`

```
public static boolean isPresent(final Class<? extends Throwable> t, final Class<?>[] exceptionArray){
    for(Class<?> exc : exceptionArray){
        if(exc.isAssignableFrom(t)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    // your code goes here
    Class<?>[] my = {RuntimeException.class};
    System.out.println(isPresent(RuntimeException.class, my));
    System.out.println(isPresent(IOException.class, my)); 
    System.out.println(isPresent(ArithmeticException.class, my));
}
```

output:

```
true
false
true
```