# Android - Is using 'instanceof' the only way to determine the type of an item returned from a Spinner in "onItemSelected"?

Tags: java, android, listener, spinner, instanceof

As in the title -

Is there any way to determine the type of the item (typically either a `String`, if adapted from a resource, or a generic `Object`, if adapted programmatically) obtained from a Spinner in `onItemSelected`? In this case, I'm referring to one filled programmatically in Java, but as far as I know, it would be the same for one created from a String resource array.

Obviously, however, we create our Spinner, ***we*** know what type everything in it is. If it's from resources, probably Strings. If done programmatically, some kind of `Object` or possibly `View`. However, the signature for `onItemSelected` looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    // actions

    // to get the item, you would usually do something like:
    parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
}
```

And obviously, the type we get from this is `?`, in other words, a generic `Object`.

So, if we know exactly what type it is, we can, of course, do this (example shown with an `Integer`):

```
Object itemSelected = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);

if (itemSelected instanceof Integer) doSomeMath((Integer) itemSelected);
```

But this doesn't exactly strike me as elegant. It works, certainly, at least in the simple cases I've given it (like `Integer`). It might even be useful for handling multiple different types of `Spinner` all running off the same `listener` - I haven't actually tried that.

But it seems like there should be a way to have the signature simply be something like:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<Integer> parent, View view, int pos, long id)
```

Comment: What's the goal here? Do you want to use the same `OnItemSelectedListener` for multiple spinners?

Comment: No, not necessarily. Just wondering if there's a better way than `instanceof` to determine the type of Object retrieved from a Spinner.

Comment: I don't think there is. Anyway, instead of doing something based on the item's type I'd rather check which spinner (`parent.getId()`) triggered the `onItemSelected` call and then act accordingly.

Comment: True - in the case of having multiple spinners handled by the same listener, at least, that seems like it would be the best way to do it. I thought about that after, as well. But regardless, you usually need to know the type to do something with it even if you do know the exact spinner it came from.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java: Class.isInstance vs Class.isAssignableFrom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949260/java-class-isinstance-vs-class-isassignablefrom)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Avoiding instanceof in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790144/avoiding-instanceof-in-java)

Comment: Add some a key mapped on every possible types to each of your Spinner Items and you can iterate on your keys instead of using "instance of" on every possible types. (if item.getKey() == SpinnerItemType.INTEGER) doStuff(...)

Answer (score 0):

> Is using 'instanceof' the only way to determine the type of an item returned from a Spinner in “onItemSelected”?

It is not the only way.  But it it probably the best way.

Here are some alternatives:

```
if (itemSelected.getClass().getName().equals("java.lang.Integer")) {
     doSomeMath((Integer) itemSelected);
}

if (itemSelected.getClass() == Integer.class) {
     doSomeMath((Integer) itemSelected);
}

try {
    doSomeMath((Integer) itemSelected);
} catch (ClassCastException ex) {
    // squash
}
```

Notes:

1. None of these alternatives is recommended.  Seriously.
2. The `instanceof` operator tests for subclasses as well, unlike the first two alternatives.
3. The third version will also squash `ClassCastException` if it is thrown in the `doSomeMath` method.
4. Problems arise with `null`.  The `instanceof` operator returns false for `null`, but all of these alternatives will throw an NPE.

---

Unfortunately, your alternative won't work.  The `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener` interface declares that method's first parameter with that type.  The interface is not generic.

Comment: Is it possible to extend the `OnItemSelectedListener` interface to create a custom version of `onItemSelected` with a particular type? Or even extend it as a generic version? For example:

`GenericItemSelectedListener<T> extends AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener`

with

`public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<T> parent...)`

?

Comment: If the other argument types are different too, yes.  Otherwise no.  But it is unclear that you would achieve anything.  How would you get the android framework to call that method?

Answer (score 0):

> But it seems like there should be a way to have the signature [...]

It seems but it can't be done because `AdapterView.getItemAtPosition(int)` returns `Object` anyway. `ListView` or `Spinner` don't know or care what type of items the adapter contains.

> Obviously, however, we create our Spinner, we know what type everything in it is.

Exactly, since you're the ultimate master of what data you put in the adapter you should be able to cast it safely

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
     final int item = (int) parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
     doSomeMath(item);
}
```

Instead of checking for an always true condition it would just crash when it encounters unexpected data.

Get into this mindset: If something happens if it's not supposed to happen the code should throw an exception. This gives you a chance to fix any errors instead of never knowing if there's anything wrong.

Another option would be having the adapter stored in a member variable and accessing it from the listener

```
private MyAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
     final int item = adapter.getItem(pos);
     doSomeMath(item);
}
```

This assumes your adapter overrides `getItem(int)` and returns the appropriate type.