# Getting object from an ArrayList<T> of a specific type in java

Tags: java, types, arraylist

I've an ArrayList, for example **b**, and i want to get an ArrayList of Worker (Worker extend Person) from that ArrayList. **b** also contains other object that extends from Person.

How can i achive that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

declare your `ArrayList` like this :

```
ArrayList<Worker> myArray = new ArrayList<Worker>()
```

Now your `ArrayList` can contain only `Worker` and the return type of its different method will be `Worker`.

And then :

```
for(Person p : b) {
    if(p instanceof Worker)
        myArray.add((Worker)p);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/index.html), it is as easy as:

```
ArrayList<Person> b;
ArrayList<Worker> a = Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.filter(b, Worker.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
List<Person> b = ...

List<Worker> workers = new ArrayList<Worker>();
for (Person p : b) {
  if (p instanceof Worker) { workers.add((Worker) p); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, i achieved my goal:

```
public ArrayList<Person> getList(Class<? extends Person> type) {
    ArrayList<Person> newList = new ArrayList<Person>();

    for (Person p : person)
        if (type.isInstance(p))
            newList.add(p);

    return newList;
}
```

i extend my problem with a dinamyc child class of person.
i hope is will usefull for others.

Answer (score -1):

When iterating through ArrayList `b` as suggested by `Krtek` and `h3r3`, consider using `Worker.class.isAssignableFrom(p.class)`. Have a look at [What is the difference between instanceof and Class.isAssignableFrom(...)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496928/what-is-the-difference-between-instanceof-and-class-isassignablefrom) for explanation on the differences.

Comment: This is not at all a good idea.  The type is known at compile time; why use reflection?  Maybe you should take a look at the link.

Comment: Why is it a bad idea Mark? Please help me to understand.