# Writing junit test for a method returning object

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I am new to writing junit tests. I am stuck at how to write tests for methods returning object. I went through this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037712/how-to-write-a-test-case-for-a-method-returning-object), but I am not convinced. I can't make changes to the method. I want to write a test for this method:

```
public final class Demo{
      public Test getTestObject() {
            return this.testObject== null ? Test.getDefaultInstance() : this.testObject;
        }
}

Test Class:
public final Test{
private Test()
{
}
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a good equals method for your Test object and use it within your unit test.
I have written a sample code.

```
public class Foo
{

  int a = 0;
  int b = 0;
  String c = "";

  public Foo(int a, int b, String c)
  {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
  }

  public static Foo getDefaultInstance()
  {
    return new Foo(1, 1, "test");
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o){
    if (o == this) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Foo)) {
        return false;
    }

    Foo foo = (Foo) o;

    return foo.a== a &&
        foo.b == b &&
            foo.c.equalsIgnoreCase(c);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
      int result = 17;
      result = 31 * result + a;
      result = 31 * result + b;
      result = 31 * result + c.hashCode();
      return result;
  }

}
```

This class contains the method that we need to test.

```
public class Other
{
  Foo foo;

  public Foo getFoo()
  {
    return this.foo == null ? Foo.getDefaultInstance() : this.foo;
  }

}
```

This is the class with test method.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class MyTest
{
  @Test
  public void testGetFoo() {
     Other other = new Other();
     Foo foo = other.getFoo();
     assertEquals(foo, new Foo(1, 1, "test"));

  }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example.I'm new to this.

Answer (score 1):

You have two branches to test :

- the `testObject` field references a not null object, so it is returned
- the `testObject` field references null, so you create it from the `getDefaultInstance()` method.

So you could define two test methods to test each scenario and assert that the expected `Test`  instance is returned.

Note that generally you should not override equals()/hashCode() only to make a unit test working.
Actually if `Test.getDefaultInstance()` returns at each time the same instance. You just need to compare two `Test` object references.
`Assert.assertSame(Object o1, Object o2)` of JUnit allowing to assert that `o1==o2` is so enough :

Supposing that the class to test is `Foo` :

```
@Test
public void getTestObject_as_null(){
   Foo foo = new Foo();
   Assert.assertSame(Test.getDefaultInstance(), foo.getTestObject());
}

@Test
public void getTestObject_as_not_null(){
   Foo foo = new Foo();
   Test test = new Test(...);
   foo.setTestObject(test);
   Assert.assertSame(test, foo.getTestObject());
}
```

It could also work with `Assert.assertEquals()` but `Assert.assertSame()` conveys better the intention of what we want to assert : the references.

On the contrary if `Test.getDefaultInstance()` returns different instances at each invocation, you should compare the content of the returned `Test` instances.
The test could look like :

```
@Test
public void getTestObject_as_null(){
   Foo foo = new Foo();
   Test expectedTest = Test.getDefaultInstance();
   Test actualTest = foo.getTestObject();
   Assert.assertEquals(expectedTest.getX(), actualTest.getX());
   Assert.assertEquals(expectedTest.getY(), actualTest.getY());
}
```

And that test don't need to change as the object referenced by `getTestObject()` and the expected Test object is necessary the same as you pass it as fixture :

```
@Test
public void getTestObject_as_not_null(){
   Foo foo = new Foo();
   Test test = new Test(...);
   foo.setTestObject(test);
   Assert.assertSame(test, foo.getTestObject());
}
```

Comment: Foo foo = new Foo();
Assert.assertSame(Test.getDefaultInstance(), foo.getTestObject());     Can you explain this?Is foo the class I want to test.If that is the case then what is Test?Sorry I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Sure ! In your question you don't specify the class of the method to test. So I named it : `Foo`. `Test` is the type returned by your method to test : `public Test getTestObject()`.
`