# Cannot compare two objects using instanceof

Tags: java, oop

When trying to compare two objects passed as arguments: first as object, second as array of objects (the same kind). Getting error `Incompatible conditional operand types Room and allRooms[]`. I am trying to iterate in `while` cycle until `thisRoomType` is not equals to some object from `rooms`. How to fix it?

```
public abstract class Room { ...}
public class LightRoom extends Room  {...}
public class DarkRoom extends Room {...}
```

Caller:

```
release(thisRoomType, rooms)
```

with parameters

```
private Room thisRoomType = this; // is defined in DarkRoom and LightRoom 
private Room[] rooms; // is defined in DarkRoom and LightRoom
```

in method:

```
public synchronized void release( Room thisRoom,  Room[] allRooms) {

        try {
            int j = 0;
            while(thisRoom instanceof allRooms[j]){     
                jj++;
            }
                        int nextRoom = jj;
...
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` waiting to happen. the `while` condition must include `jj < allRooms.length`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
while (j < allRooms.length && thisRoom.getClass().equals(allRooms[j].getClass()))
```

Comment: @RCola sorry, you saw a previous version of my answer. Try with the updated one.

Comment: @ewernli I'm not sure if that's a problem. Because as stated, OP's question will _always_ loop until an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` occurs, a non-null `Room` will always be an instance of any non-null element in a `Room[]`. The code might only make sense if a different kind of room is encountered, and that's what my answer does.

Comment: The equivalent of instanceof is isAssignableFrom. See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496928/what-is-the-difference-between-instanceof-and-class-isassignablefrom

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is wrong.
`instanceof` expects a `ReferenceType` while you are passing **an object instance** `allRooms[j]`. This can never work.
What you should be doing is:

1. compare with `package` names or
2. `class` names or
3. compare against the concrete classes (`getClass`).

Pick according to your needs