# typecheck for generic interface in Java

Tags: java, generics

I have a Interface IEvent that looks like this:

```
public abstract interface IEvent<T> {
    public abstract void handleEvent(T payload);
}
```

and 2 Interfaces with a concrete generic type that looks like this:

```
public interface IKeyDownEvent extends IEvent<KeyDownEventPayload> {}
public interface IKeyUpEvent extends IEvent<KeyUpEventPayload> {}
```

Both KeyUpEvent and KeyDownEvent are extending from EventPayload.

How do I go about and iterate over a ArrayDeque and only call handleEvent() for classes that implement IKeyDownEvent but not for example IKeyUpEvent?

I tried this but it seem to not work:

```
if (payload.getClass() == ev.getClass().getGenericSuperclass())
    ev.handleEvent(payload);
```

Comment: _"concrete Interfaces "_ -- Sorry, there's no such thing. Interfaces cannot be "concrete".  Have you considered `instanceof`?

Comment: @JimGarrison Seems obvious that OP is referring to a non-abstract interface.

Comment: _"non-abstract interface"_ -- Also no such thing. Do you mean "non-generic"?

Comment: Oh my word. Seems obvious that I was referring to an interface that is not abstract.

Comment: I guess "concrete interface" = interface with concrete generic types.

Comment: Maybe this question helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145185/determine-if-a-class-implements-a-interface-in-java

Comment: "abstract" and "concrete" have very specific meanings. Let's not abuse them please

Comment: "...classes that implement IKeyDownEvent but not for example IKeyUpEvent" - Note that you'd run into problems properly implementing `handleEvent()` in classes that implement both. You'd probably be better off with separate methods like `onKeyDown(KeyDownEventPayload)` etc. Could you elaborate (best with some more code) on what you actually try to achieve with `IEvent<T>`? I have the strong feeling that this is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Jim Garrison I ment a interfact with a concrete generic type, sorry.

Comment: @Thomas I want something like this: https://pastebin.com/Mde19T67 The Reason why I want it like that is so that you can add your own events without changing code in the eventHandler

Comment: Please don't post such small amounts of code as external links but rather add them to your question. Links can get invalid and often are inconvenient anyways (e.g. having to switch between the linked page and here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To literally answer your question, use `Class.getGenericInterfaces` instead of `Class.getGenericSuperclass` as `IEvent` is an immediately super interface and not an immediate superclass. Or arguably better particularly now we don't have interface `interface`, make `IEvent` an abstract class.

Still that very fragile. Only checking the immediate types, for instance. Also checking runtime types is such a bad idea.

Better, don't put the `IEvent` straight in to the `Deque`. Wrap `IKeyDownEvent` in a class that deals with `KeyDownEventPayload` correctly, and similarly for other types.