# Compare object type

Tags: java, types

I don't know how to perform type checking on newEntry, I want to make sure that it is of type MyTable (without creating an object of MyTable).

```
public static boolean add(String table, Object newEntry)
{
    boolean result; 
    if (table.equals("MyTable") && newEntry.getClass() == MyTable.getClass())
    {
         ...
    }   
}
```

My problem is:

```
newEntry.getClass() == MyTable.getClass().
```

Note: MyTable is a class name, not an object.

Comment: newEntry instanceof Table ?

Answer (score 5):

Basically what you want is:

> isAssignableFrom

Take a look at: http://www.ralfebert.de/blog/java/isassignablefrom/

So, in your case, you want:

> MyTable.class.isAssignableFrom(newEntry.getClass())

Comment: Thanks, that got the job done. However, I'm wondering why instanceOf wouldn't work. Instance of was my first approach . .

Comment: It has to do with which class you mention first and which one last. For example, newEntry.getClass().isAssignableFrom(MyTable.class) wouldn't probably work for you either. Try flipping the arguments and the instanceof should start to work as well.

Answer (score 3):

Use [**instanceof**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2) operator .. Refer to the JLS for more documentation

Check this famous answer [What is the difference between instanceof and Class.isAssignableFrom(...)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496928/what-is-the-difference-between-instanceof-and-class-isassignablefrom)

Answer (score 2):

`instanceof` is your friend:

```
if (table.equals("MyTable") && newEntry instanceof MyTable)
```

It is actually a shorthand for the `isAssignableFrom` method, but it's much easier to type :)

Comment: @syb0rg hurrying towards 3000 :D

Comment: @syb0rg kind of you, made my day complete :) now do the cleanup :)

Answer (score 2):

Compare with [`instanceof`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313559/what-is-the-instanceof-operator-used-for).

```
if (newEntry instanceof MyTable) {
    // do something
  }
```

In this example, the condition is true if `newEntry` is an instance of `MyTable`, or if `newEntry` is an instance of a superclass of `MyTable`.

Change your statement to this to make it work properly:

```
if (table.equals("MyTable") && newEntry instanceof MyTable)
```

---

You could also use `isAssignableFrom()` to compare them.  The reason you might want to do this is because with `instanceof`, you have to know the class you are comparing before you compile your program.  With `isAssignableFrom()`, you can change the class you are comparing to during run-time.

```
if (table.equals("MyTable") && MyTable.class.isAssignableFrom(newEntry.getClass()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MyTable.class` to retrieve the class name.

Comment: @JHollanti, because answer needs to be at least 30 characters