# The equivalent of instanceof

Tags: java, if-statement, instanceof

What is the equivalent of this without using instanceof? Maybe something more simple while using true, false or else statements?

```
public static void p (Object...ar)
{
        for (int i=0; i < ar.length; i++)
        {
                if (ar[i] instanceof int[])
                {
```

Comment: Why do you need an alternative?

Comment: So I can better understand instanceof.

Comment: RTTI is usually considered a "code smell". Tough there are particular cases where I can understand its use, I'd rather take a polymorphc approach. There's not much to `instanceof` actually, the docs explain it pretty well: *The instanceof operator compares an object to a specified type. You can use it to test if an object is an instance of a class, an instance of a subclass, or an instance of a class that implements a particular interface.*

Comment: There really isn't something lower level than `instanceof`; there are only higher-level things and entirely different approaches to the same problem.

Comment: @LouisWasserman There's the Class method `isInstance` which isn't really higher level or entirely different.

Comment: I'm kind of new at Java. I was looking for something more simple while using true, false or else statements?

Comment: You have the three basic elements you need to check a type, an input (`ar[i]`), a type reference (`int[]`) and an operator that does the check (`instanceof`). What sould be simpler than that for you?.

Comment: I am trying to use true, false, or else operators instead of instanceof

Comment: None of `true`, `false`, or `else` are operators. They're constants and keywords.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For primitive arrays you can, instead of:

```
if (ar[i] instanceof int[])
```

Use:

```
if (ar[i].getClass() == int[].class)
```

**Note:**
The above code works fine for arrays of primitive types. Please be aware, though, that `instanceof` also checks if the object in the left-part is a subtype of the class in the right-part, while `==` does not.
For **objects**, the equivalent to `(myInstance instanceof MyClass[])` (checks for subtyping) is:

```
(   MyClass[].class.isAssignableFrom(  myInstance.getClass()  )   )
```

Comment: One thing to note: this has the downside (or possibly upside, if this is error which *should* throw, but usually not) that if `ar[i]` is null, this will throw `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Note that in general `a instanceof A` does _not_ imply `a.getClass() == A.class`

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
(getClass().isArray())
```

and checking if integer array:

```
 ar.getClass().toString().equals("class [I")
```

**updated**:

```
if(ar.getClass().isArray()) {
        if(ar[i].getClass() == int[].class)
            ....
        else if(ar[i].getClass() == String[].class)
            ....
}
```

Comment: What about the data type check (i.e. it's an array of *integers*)?

Comment: check out Class.getComponentType()

Comment: I'm kind of new at Java. I was looking for something more simple while using true, false or else statements?

Comment: Is there any value to the `ar.getClass().isArray()` check when you check against array types further down?

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to just assume it is an `int[]`, and catch the resulting exception if it is not:

```
public static void p (Object...ar)
{
    for (int i=0; i < ar.length; i++)
    {
        int[] i_arr;
        try {
            i_arr = (int[]) ar[i];
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            continue;
        }
        //...
```

Comment: you are using exceptions as flow control, something that should be avoided

Comment: -1 for using exceptions as flow control, especially when simple alternatives exist.

Comment: Something more simple than this? While using true, false, or else?

Comment: @JavaMentor: Am I? Is this any different to trying to open a file, and skipping it if it doesn't exist? That throws an exception too. Are exceptions not at some level for flow control? Otherwise, they're be error codes.

Comment: No, exceptions should present a situation that isn't expected. Otherwise you will have just `Go-To`s within your code. You can find more about this topic [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05254/index.html)

Comment: I'm not sure I completely agree with that. At some level you expect it, else you'd never catch it. Having said that, in the context of java, [CheckDontCatch](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CheckDontCatch) indicates this is probably a bad idea.

Comment: I'm kind of new at Java. I was looking for something more simple while using true, false or else statements?

Comment: @JavaMentor: Well, you can't use `instance of` per the OP so he is doing it an alternative way.

Comment: wouldn't it be solved using `ar[i].getClass() == int[].class` in a condition?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, inheritance and polymorphism is a better solution to your problem. Rather than check what kind of object you are dealing with, have several classes inherit from a generic class, and call the shared methods.

Comment: In case of arrays this is not possible.

Comment: Wait, are you storing objects or arrays? Because it does work just fine in arrays if you are storing different kinds of objects in arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Check out java.lang.Class, which has a method `isAssignableFrom(Class<?> cls)`

For your specific example with arrays, it also has    `isArray()` and `getComponentType()`

Answer (score 0):

```
Class<?> intArrayCls = int[].class;

...

if (intArrayCls.isInstance(ar[i])) {
```

Would do the trick too.

[JavaDoc of isInstance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29). It is a little more flexible as it doesn't just test equality like the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

use isAssignableFrom

```
public static void test(Object... args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
       if (args[i].getClass().isAssignableFrom(int[].class)) {
        System.out.println("true");
       } else {
            System.out.println("false");
       }
    }
}
```

you can use isAssignableFrom in a dynamic way too, see this post to know the difference between instanceof and isAssignableFrom
[What is the difference between instanceof and Class.isAssignableFrom(...)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496928/what-is-the-difference-between-instanceof-and-class-isassignablefrom)