# How to find specific types in a java set

Tags: java, collections

i have a class heirarchy,

```
Class b extends class a 
Class c extends class a
```

All the three classes can be instantiated.
Now objects of these three types are added to a `Set`.

I am required to traverse this set and find out the instances of type c and then do some processing on that.

Currently I am traversing the set and checking each entry if its a instanceof c .

Is there a better way of doing this?
Something in the `Collections` library itself?

Comment: Why not you using three different `Set`s for each class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify your desired behavior exactly. It *sounds* like you only want the exact instances of `c`, not instances of any class derived from `c`.

If that is the case, use [`Object.getClass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass()):

```
x.getClass().equals(c.class);
```

This will be true if `x` is an instance of `c`, and *not* true if `x` is an instance of a class derived from `c`.

If that is not the case, use [`instanceof`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496928/what-is-the-difference-between-instanceof-and-class-isassignablefrom):

```
x instanceof c
```

This will be true if `x` is an instance of `c`, and *also* true if `x` is an instance of a class derived from `c`.

Whichever one you pick, from there you want to use an iterator:

```
Iterator<a> iter = set.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()) {
    a item = iter.next()
    if(item[.getClass().equals(c.class)| instanceof c]) {
        // do something with item
    }
}
```

Of course, this is a common pattern, and there are [libraries](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/wiki/LambdajFeatures) that encapsulate this logic.

Comment: yeah well i want want exact instances of c .

Comment: you need isassignablefrom http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496928/what-is-the-difference-between-instanceof-and-class-isassignablefrom - also while == is ok in this case, it is really bad practice to not use .equals to compare anything that is non-primitive in Java

Comment: @Tom Carchrae: No, `Class.isAssignableFrom` isn't needed here; he knows the type at compile time, so comparing the result of `Object.getClass` to `c.class` is okay. `Class.isAssignableFrom` is useful when you don't know the type at compile time.

Comment: uh - rather, you don't need isAssignableFrom - somehow i read that wrong.  in practice, i would avoid using instanceof because someone who extends your class will get a surprise.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into [lambdaj](https://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/). It lets you manipulate collections in a functional programming-esque way. Make a predicate like so:

```
Matcher<A> f = new Predicate<A>() {
    public boolean apply(A item) {
        return item instanceof C;
    }
};
```

And then just filter using that predicate. Simple!

```
filter(f, collection)
```

For more, here's a blog post outlining various methods: http://guidogarcia.net/blog/2011/10/29/java-different-ways-filter-collection/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is a possibility for you but you could use Google Guava and use a filter on that set. Have your Predicate do the instanceof logic and then if true it will filter the set based on that.

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html

Answer (score 1):

You can optionnally index classes of each inserted objects but it mainly depend on how many items are in the Set and the rate of C instances.

Here is a sample class :

```
public class IndexedSet<T> {
  private Map<T,T> container = new HashMap<T,T>();
  private Map<Class<?>, Map<T,T>> indexByClass = new IdentityHashMap<Class<?>, Map<T,T>>();

  public boolean add(T e) {
    if (e == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't add null");
    }
    if (container.containsKey(e)) return false;

    container.put(e, e);
    Map<T,T> indexEntry = indexByClass.get(e.getClass());
    if (indexEntry == null) {
      indexEntry = new IdentifyHashMap<T,T>();
      indexByClass.put(e.getClass(), indexEntry);
    }
    indexEntry.put(e,e);
    return true;
  }

  public boolean remove(T e) {
    e = container.remove(e);
    if (removed == null) return false;

    Map<T,T> indexEntry = indexByClass.get(e.getClass());
    indexEntry.remove(e);

    return true;
  }

  public Set<T> getAll() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableSet(container.keySet());
  }

  public Set<T> getByClass(Class<?> clazz) {
    Map<T,T> indexEntry = indexByClass.get(clazz);
    return indexEntry != null ? Collections.unmodifiableSet(indexEntry.keySet()) : null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`SetMultimap<Class<?>, A>`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/SetMultimap.html) to map from the concrete class to a set of instances of that class, and still have the `containsValue` methods which would correspond to the `contains` method in your original set.