# How do I use getClass() to tell if an Object is numeric?

Tags: java, reflection

I want to dynamically tell if an Object in Java is numeric or not. My code is as the following:

```
if(obj.getClass().equals(Number.class)) {
    attributeTypeStr = "Numeric";
} else {
    attributeTypeStr = "Non-Numeric";
}
```

The `Object obj` can be any numeric types like `Integer, Float, Double`, etc. But when I tested it with `Integer/Float/Double`, the `attributeTypeStr` always returns `"Non-Numeric"`. I guess that's because `Integer/Float/Double` are subclasses of `Number` but `Number.class` does not equal `Double.class`. I could use something like

```
if(obj.getClass().equals(Integer.class) || obj.getClass().equals(Float.class) || obj.getClass().equals(Double.class))
```

But it looks too verbose. So is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: Why not `obj instanceof Number`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `instanceof`:

```
if (obj instanceof Number)
```

Comment: I honestly hadn't used `instanceof` in so long, I forgot it existed.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`Class#isAssignableFrom(Class)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29) which states

> Determines if the class or interface represented by this Class object
>   is either the same as, or is a superclass or superinterface of, the
>   class or interface represented by the specified Class parameter.

Doing

```
Integer obj = new Integer(2);       
System.out.println(Number.class.isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass()));
```

will therefore print `true`.

It might not be relevant to your question, but just fyi:

- [What is the difference between instanceof and Class.isAssignableFrom(…)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496928/what-is-the-difference-between-instanceof-and-class-isassignablefrom)

Comment: While I won't dispute that this works, wouldn't instanceof Number be a simpler call to make? (Nit pick) I'd, personally, use this if I only had the Class reference, so, yes, it has its uses

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yeah, just giving options.

Comment: Wouldn't this break if type information is unavailable at runtime?(the OP's skeleton would break as well, but for future reference)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: This gives another option. It seems that `isAssignableFrom()` is more flexible and powerful than `instanceof`, right?

Comment: @tonga It adds possibilities. For example, if you didn't know you were trying to assign to `Number` specifically, but to the class of an Object, you could just `getClass()` on that object and call `isAssignableFrom()` on the return `Class<?>` instance.

Comment: @hexafraction: What situation will break this? `isAssignableFrom()` can handle class type at runtime, right?

Comment: Note that this does not work if you try to test a class object for a primitive type. For example: `Number.class.isAssignableFrom(int.class)` is false. (This does not matter if you test a value that is held in a `Object` reference of course, only when you test a class object you get from somewhere.)

Answer (score 1):

Check its superclass. This works as these classes are *direct* superclasses:

```
if(obj.getClass().getSuperclass().equals(Number.class)){
    //logic
}
```

Or for non-direct, check `Number.class.isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass())`. For numeric, it shouldn't be very much of a problem as the existing Number subclasses are **final**. In gnerics, this may break due to the absence of type information.

Comment: It seems that I need to use `o.getClass().getSuperclass().equals(Number.class)` to get it correct.

Comment: @tonga Yup, my typo. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Use `isInstance()` method of `Class`

```
if(Number.class.isInstance(obj)){
}
```

According to [Class#isInstance()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Class%29)

> Determines if the specified Object is assignment-compatible with the object represented by this Class. This method is the dynamic equivalent of the Java language instanceof operator. The method returns true if the specified Object argument is non-null and can be cast to the reference type represented by this Class object without raising a ClassCastException. It returns false otherwise.