# Get field name and check array list is there?

Tags: java, android, reflection

With below method I can pass any class  and I can get values of the list.

```
public static void GetFieldName(ArrayList<Object> object)
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {

    for (Object obj : object)
        for (Field field : obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            Log.i("Field", field.getName() + ":" + field.get(obj));

        }
    }
```

Suppose I have two classes `Student` and `Employee`. I don't know how many fields are there in both of them. Still I can get value of every field using the above method.

Now, I want to check if a particular class has any ArrayList within, i.e Suppose the `Student` class has an `Arraylist<Address>` of `Address` class. So can I get the array list values?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [Class#isAssignableFrom(Class cls)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29) method.

```
for (Field field : obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
    Log.i("Field", field.getName() + ":" + field.get(obj));
    if (field.getType().isAssignableFrom(ArrayList.class) {
        field.setAccessible(true); //needed for private fields 
        Object value = field.get(c); //getting the private field value
        ArrayList<Address> x = (ArrayList<Address>) value; // cast to ArrayList<Address>
    }
}
```

More info:

- [Difference between instanceof and isAssignableFrom()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496928/what-is-the-difference-between-instanceof-and-class-isassignablefrom)

Comment: How can I get value from arraylist if condition is true?

Comment: Checkout the [Field](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html) javadoc.

Comment: Try `Object value = field.get(obj)`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37775/discussion-between-nil-and-kocko)

Comment: I have asked this question "So can I get that array list values?", You have given half answer. that's why I have unaccepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can call getDeclaringClass() on field object and compare it to desired class (e.g. ArrayList)