# Is down casting considered bad practice?

Tags: java, object

So, I have a set up like below where `A` and `B` are both `abstract` classes.

```
abstract class ObjectA extends ObjectB<ObjectC> {

}

public class ObjectD extends ObjectA{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ObjectA x = new ObjectD();
        ObjectD y = (ObjectD)x; // down cast
    }

}
```

I'm using a library where I want to avail of the abstract methods in `ObjectB` and provide a default constructor for all classes - `ObjectA`. I'm not sure on my approach. BTW `ObjectB` is part of a predefine library I'm using. `ObjectA` is my own class providing default properties and constructor.

I'm not so sure on my approach, doesn't seem nice?

Just to add:

ObjectA requires a type that extends ObjectA.

```
public abstract class ObjectA<T extends ObjectA<T>> {

}
```

Hence, the need for what I'm doing.

Comment: Why not just declare the variable as the specific type in the first place?

Comment: If you know what you are doing, its not bad..

Comment: @chrylis answered in edit

Comment: It's still not clear why you don't just declare `ObjectD xy = new ObjectD()` in place of the declarations of x and y.

Comment: @Thedore Norvell because I will have several different classes extending from ObjectD class.

Answer (score 2):

Note that in some cases you might get *runtime error* because by the *explicit cast* you're telling the compiler to trust you that you're not making errors, so it'll ignore the errors and won't detect it in compilation time.

As long as you know what you're doing, that's fine. To be safe, you can always use `instanceof`.

Comment: Take a look at this post, also very helpful to suit your needs 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496928/what-is-the-difference-between-instanceof-and-class-isassignablefrom