# How to make this method more generic

Tags: java, inheritance, collections, casting

i am having some trouble figuring something regarding inheritance in Java. I thought it would be straightforward but it has stumped me.

I have this superclass..

```
public class MyItem {

    private String barCode;
    private String price;

    public String getBarCode() {
        return barCode;
    }

    public void setBarCode(String barCode) {
        this.barCode = barCode;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

}
```

And i have these 2 subclasses

```
public class PromotionalItem extends MyItem {

    private String promotion;

    public String setPromotion(String promotion) {
        this.promotion = promotion;
    }

    public void getPromotion() {
        this.promotion = promotion;
    }

}

public class SellableItem extends MyItem {

    private String quantity;

    public String setQuantity(String quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public void getQuantity() {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

}
```

Now i have a method that i want to make generic, i thought something like this could work...

```
public void processItem(MyItem item){
    if(item.getClass().isAssignableFrom(PromotionalItem.class)){
        processPromotionalItem((PromotionalItem)item);
    }
    else{
        processSellableItem((SellableItem)item);
    }
}
```

But I am getting a ClassCastException when i try to cast these items as their respective subclasses. I thought something like this would be do-able. Am i missing something? What is the alternative do something like this?

Comment: Add a method to the superclass and call it inside processItem, then if the method is overridden in the sub class that method will get called instead

Comment: "But I am getting a ClassCastException" can't reproduce. Use [edit] option and provide [mcve].

Comment: `item.getClass().isAssignableFrom(PromotionalItem.class)` makes no sense. Apparently, you mean `PromotionalItem.class.isAssignableFrom(item.getClass())`, but it’s much easier to write the idiomatic `item instanceof PromotionalItem`. Then, you can’t make such mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks like an anti-pattern. What I would do is have an abstract method called process in MyItem and have both subclasses implementing that method:

```
public class MyItem {

    private String barCode;
    private String price;

    public String getBarCode() {
        return barCode;
    }

    public void setBarCode(String barCode) {
        this.barCode = barCode;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public abstract void process();

}
```

Now if you have a subclass you are forced to implement the process method, and then instead of checking what class it is you can just call the process method directly.

```
public void processItem(MyItem item){
    item.process();
}
```

Comment: The thing is, in the process methods im actually using Jackson to convert the objects to JSON, so there isn't any "processing" happening per say

Answer (score 1):

Make `MyClass` abstract and add an abstract `process` method, like @JoakimDanielson suggested. Then, in your child classes, override that method and implement your own logic.

```
public abstract class MyItem {
    ...
    public abstract void process();
}

public class PromotionalItem extends MyItem {
    ...
    @Override
    public void process() {
        // do whatever
    }
}

 public class SellableItem extends MyItem {
    ...
    @Override
    public void process() {
        // do whatever
    }
}
```

Then, in your `processItem` method, just call `process`:

```
public void processItem(MyItem item) {
    item.process();
}
```

Comment: The thing is, these are getting converted to JSON, so i cant really abstract them like this. Theres no processing thats done.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `instanceof` keyword

```java
if(item instanceof PromotionalItem){
    processPromotionalItem((PromotionalItem) item);
} else if(item instanceof SellableItem) {
    processSellableItem((SellableItem) item);
}
```

> Make sure you use `else if` not only `else` because item might be
>   something else other than `PromotionalItem` and `SellableItem` if you
>   cast it to a class from which it wasn't build from, you will get a `ClassCastException`

*`instanceof` is a keyword that is used for checking if a reference variable is containing a given type of object reference or not.*

Comment: But what problem `item instanceof PromotionalItem` solves in comparison to `item.getClass().isAssignableFrom(PromotionalItem.class)`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496928/what-is-the-difference-between-instanceof-and-class-isassignablefrom

Comment: But what in case of OP problem? In question we can read that current code throws `ClassCastException`. Would using `item instanceof PromotionalItem` instead prevent it? If no then what is the point of that change?

Comment: Because he has to use `else if` not only `else` because item may neither be both

Answer (score 0):

In your case you should use `instanceof` instead of `isAssignableFrom` (be careful though, the syntax is different, more on that below).

`isAssignableFrom` checks if the parameter object can be written to the object the function has been called from. `instanceof` checks if the left object is from the same class or a subclass of the right class. This will make more sense once you've seen the syntax of `instanceof`:

```
if(item instanceof PromotionalItem){
    processPromotionalItem((PromotionalItem)item);
}
```

So in a nutshell, your logic was just a little off. You were trying to cast from one subclass of your item class to a completely different subclass.

Answer (score 0):

I‘ll only address the issue, as there are enough solutions (I think @Major Ben s one is nice)

```
item.getClass().isAssignableFrom(PromotionalItem.class)
```

What this line means is:
„Can I assign to the dynamic class of `item`  an instance of `PromotionalItem`.“

But now consider this - is it legal?

```
MyItem item = new PromotionalItem();
```

Yes, it is. So this will *always* be true. Hence, you then try to cast to `PromotionalItem`, even when it is actually not ok.

Also have a look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3657960/2995907

Answer (score 0):

Using abstract class which is great. We can think also with generices like

```
public class MyItem<T extends MyItem> {

    private String barCode;
    private String price;

    public String getBarCode() { return barCode; }

    public void setBarCode(String barCode) { this.barCode = barCode; }

    public String getPrice() { return price; }

    public void setPrice(String price) { this.price = price; }

    public void process(T item) {
        if(item instanceof PromotionalItem){
            System.out.println("PromotionalItem");
            //do something for promotionalItem
        } else if(item instanceof SellableItem) {
            System.out.println("SellableItem");
            //do something for SellableItem
        }
    }
}


public class PromotionalItem extends MyItem {

    private String promotion;

    public void setPromotion(String promotion) {
        this.promotion = promotion;
    }

    public String getPromotion() {
        return promotion;
    }
}


public class SellableItem extends MyItem {

    private String quantity;

    public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public String getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

}


    @Test
    public void test_porecessItem() {
        PromotionalItem promotionalItem = new PromotionalItem();
        SellableItem sellableItem = new SellableItem();
        MyItem<PromotionalItem> promotionalItemMyItem = new MyItem<>();
        MyItem<SellableItem> sellableItemMyItem = new MyItem<>();
        promotionalItem.process(promotionalItem);
        sellableItemMyItem.process(sellableItem);
    }
```

By the way, this is just an option which we can think.