# Why does Java generics doesnot allow returning its own type if the type is extended from anotehr class?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, overloading

I have the DBMapper class that extends RowMapper. I parameterized it since two different mappings need to be done for two different different data sets. here is the code:

```
public class DBMapper<T> extends RowMapper<T>{
 
 T t;

 @Override
 public T mapRow (ResultSet rs, int rowNum){
   return mapData(t, rs, rowNum);
 }

 private <T extends B> T mapData(T data, ResultSet rs, int rowNum){
   //TODO mapping operations for Class B
    return data;
 }

 private <T extends C> T mapData(T data, ResultSet rs, int rowNum){
  //TODO mapping operations for class C
   return data;
 }
```

Here I am getting an error in the return statement of mapRow method. The error is

```
The method mapData(T extends B, ResultSet, int) in the type DBMapper<T> is not applicable for the arguments (T, ResultSet, int)
```

It is returning the type T which is valid. Even if T is extending another class, still it is type T that is returned. Why am I getting the above error?

Comment: What is `T` in scope of call site? Looks like it is different `T`.

Comment: Do you mean that if `T` is `B` (or subclass thereof), you want the `mapData` call to call the `private <T extends B> T mapData(...)` overload? And if `T` is `C` (or subclass thereof), you want it to call the `private <T extends C> T mapData(...)` overload?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, correct

Comment: you could do a if-check in the `mapRow` method. if(t instanceof B){...}. and call appropriate methods (e.g. mapDataToB, mapDataToC). And you should consider what happens if `t` is null. Then you would get an exception because of ambiguous method call

Comment: What if `T` is neither `B` nor `C`? What if `T` is `String` or `Integer`? I think `DBMapper` should be made into an abstract class, and `mapData` should be an abstract method. You should then have two classes - `AMapper` and `BMapper` that inherit `DBMapper` and implement `mapData` in their own ways. Will that work in your situation?

Comment: @Sweeper As an alternative, I could have two class that extends RowMapper. But I am trying to confine the code in a single class if that is possible.

Comment: It _is_ possible, like benebo22 has said, but I really don't see any advantage of doing this in one class. Why do you want to keep it in a single class?

Comment: @Sweeper I did, what benebo22 suggested, but still the error did not go away. Keeping in a single class would not do anything with performance. I am just looking towards maintaining the code as I already have a lot of classes

Comment: Just to note: The `T` in `<T extends B>` is _not_ related to the `T` from `class DBMapper<T>`; they're two separate type variables that happen to have the same name. Not sure if that affects your design choices.

Comment: Your type parameters T in the methods mapData() are hiding your original type Parameter. You should get a warning "The type parameter T is hiding the type T". Change e.g. the 'T' to an 'R'

Answer (score 2):

Your type parameters T in the methods mapData() are hiding your original type Parameter. You should get a warning "The type parameter T is hiding the type T". As @Slaw pointed out in a comment, this method type parameter is an entirely new parameter, independent from the original T, just that you gave it the same name and thus hiding the other.

Furthermore the type parameters of Java Generics are not present anymore at runtime (keyword 'type erasure'). Therefore, even when you get rid of this error-message, this kind of case distinction between the types of T at runtime is unfortunately not possible using only the Java-Generics-syntax.

So either, as @Sweeper suggested, you have to make two different implementations in different classes, or you take the approach by @beneboo22 which you apparently prefer and do the instanceof-checking in only one single `mapData()` method with return type `T` (no additional type parameter):

```
private T mapData(T data, ResultSet rs, int rowNum){
     if (data instanceof B) {
         return data; //TODO implement map
     }
     if (data instanceof C) {
         return data; //TODO implement map
     }

     return data; // TODO implement default map
 }
```

@Sweeper 's solution instead would look like:

```
public abstract class DBMapper<T> extends RowMapper<T>{
 T t;

 @Override
 public T mapRow (ResultSet rs, int rowNum){
   return mapData(t, rs, rowNum);
 }

 abstract T mapData(T data, ResultSet rs, int rowNum);
}

class BMapper extends DBMapper<B>{
     @Override
     B mapData(B data, ResultSet rs, int rowNum){
         return data; //TODO implement map
     }
}
class CMapper extends DBMapper<C>{
     @Override
     C mapData(C data, ResultSet rs, int rowNum){
         return data; //TODO implement map
     }
}
```

(**Edit:** @dmitryvim 's answer seems equivalent to the instanceof approach to me. It would be different, if one could use `T.class` instead of `t.getClass()`, but because of type erasure, the former is not known at runtime anymore.)

Answer (score 1):

```
public class DBMapper<T> extends RowMapper<T> {  


 T t;

 @Override
 public T mapRow (ResultSet rs, int rowNum){
   if (B.class.isAssignableFrom(t.getClass())) {
     return mapDataB(t, rs, rowNum);
   }
   if (C.class.isAssignableFrom(t.getClass())) {
     return mapDataC(t, rs, rowNum);
   }
   throw new IllegalArgumentException();
 }

 private <T extends B> T mapDataB(T data, ResultSet rs, int rowNum){
   //TODO mapping operations for Class B
    return data;
 }

 private <T extends C> T mapDataC(T data, ResultSet rs, int rowNum){
  //TODO mapping operations for class C
   return data;
 }

}
```

Comment: that still has the same problem of hiding the type T in the two mapData - maps. In addition, it should be "t.getClass()" (brackets missing).

Comment: But the approach is interesting as you don't seem to use runtime-types. Couldn't you just remove the type parameters of mapDataB and mapDataC and just give them return type (and first argument type) B and C respectively? But that would require a cast in mapRow() and the compiler doesn't allow this. So I don't see how to fix this approach ...

Comment: ah, sorry, realized that it's enough to remove the type parameter <T> but leave the type T for both maps. Then it should work.

Comment: just realized that t.getClass() is of course still the runtime class. So my previous remark about your approach not needing runtime-types seems wrong. How does it then differ from the instanceof - approach?

Comment: It depends on your purposes and code organisation. Maybe you need a `Map<Class<A>, Function<A, A>>` (hello Spring) It is just one more approach.

Comment: @dimitryvim not sure if I get your point. In your Code one could simply replace `B.class.isAssignableFrom(t.getClass())` with `t instanceof B`, ending up with beneboo22 suggestion. Don't see how this would organize the code much differently. I understand that there are situations where the method `isAssignableFrom` behaves different and is really needed, but here I wouldn't see any advantage. (see e.g. [here]([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496928/what-is-the-difference-between-instanceof-and-class-isassignablefrom)). But one can certainly use it, if one prefers...

Comment: @dimitryvim BTW, a few days ago I provided a suggested edit to the code of your post, as it simply doesn't compile as it is. Not sure if you could see this suggested edit, but it was rejected by two of three reviewers, saying that it would change the intent of the author. I don't think, it would, so maybe you can do the edit yourself, if you agree: first add brackets to t.getClass() at two places and second remove the type parameters <T extends B> and <T extends C> as they're hiding the original  T and you'll get the same compiler error as in the original question.

Comment: @Sebastian, it will really change my idea. 
I know too few about the Kiran problem, but I like your response above more than mine.
But my approach can be more suitable in case you need some kind a registry of mappers, so you can add field `Map<Class<?>, Mapper<T>>` and register different mappers based on configuration. And it cannot be implemented with `instanceOf` usage

Comment: thanks for your reply @dmitryvim . I'm sorry that I apparently misunderstood your intentions. I wouldn't have edited if I had thought that it might change your idea.
 The idea with the Mapper-registry sounds interesting, but for the moment I'd just like to see how you would get rid of your compiler error if not the way I suggested.  Or are you saying, you would need the details of the problem to give the correct fix there?

Comment: the more precise problem described, the more precise reply can be. When you have just technical question I can share only several ways how it can be resolved
Your comment - one solution, my comment - another solution

Comment: sorry to be so insisting. I'm really happy that you provided another suggestion, I even upvoted it, but I'm confused why you don't want to get rid off the compiler errors of your code. Do you agree that it does not compile? I just wanted to fix this, in order to make it more useful for readers.

Comment: yes, for my solution classes B and C should be defined. And closing bracket should be added at the last line. What other changes would you like to add?

Comment: your class DBMapper is missing the member `T t` and even after adding that and the bracket and all the missing classes (I didn't mind the missing classes), you will still get an error 
"The method mapDataB(T extends B, ResultSet, int) in the type DBMapper<T> is not applicable for the arguments (T, ResultSet, int)"
This is exactly the same error as in the original question, because you still introduce additional type parameters `<T extends B>` and `<T extends C>` which hide the original T. That's why I suggested to remove these and write instead simply `private T mapDataB(...)`.

Comment: in addition it should be `t.getClass()` with brackets at two places.

Comment: @dimitryvim maybe you can see the edit that I suggested previously:
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/29579415 
it is still missing the bracket that you mentioned and the member `T t`, but then it should be complete.