# Using instanceof to seperate classes in an ArrayList

Tags: java, class, arraylist, instanceof

apologies if this is simple or has been answered before, I'm new to Java and in my research I can't find too much on this issue and have not yet found a solution.

I have an ArrayList with multiple classes that all share a common Interface, in this example the interface is called "*Packable*". I'm trying to create a method that takes a class parameter and sweeps through each element of this ArrayList, **returning a new list containing all the items in the original list that are of the same class as the reference parameter.**

This is my code so far, trying the *instanceof* method:

```
 public List<Packable> getOfType(Packable reference){
        List<Packable> typeOfItems = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Packable item: itemsStored) {
            if (item instanceof reference){
                typeOfItems.add(item);
            }
        }
        return typeOfItems;
    }
```

This is throwing an error as it doesn't yet recognise reference as a class. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496928/what-is-the-difference-between-instanceof-and-class-isassignablefrom) mentions  a method *isAssignableFrom* with the answer stating: "*When using instanceof, you need to know the class of B at compile time. When using isAssignableFrom() it can be dynamic and change during runtime.*" (Thanks [Marc Novakowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27020/marc-novakowski))

I understand that given the parameter the class isn't known at compilation and as such I've tried implementing isAssignableFrom and can't really seem to get it to work. The IDE doesn't really recognise or suggest it, and there isn't too much about the method online. I've tried implementing it the way the JavaDocs suggest but this isn't working either:

```
if (reference.isAssignableFrom(item.getClass())){
                typeOfItems.add(item);
            }
```

Any help or advice on methods to look into would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for reading the question, and again apologies if this is simple or has been answered elsewhere and I've just missed it. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what `Packable` is, but you appear to be confused about a few concepts here.

In java, `Packable reference` **does not represent the `Packable` concept**. It represents a specific instance of Packable (or null).

In other words, given `Dog dog`, that means dog is some *specific* dog. Not 'the general concept of a dog'. We know that the specific animal that `dog` is referring to is, at least, a Dog. It could be Fifi, the neighbour's schnauzer.

`instanceof`, on the other hand, is about the general concept of things: `if (fifi instanceof Dog)` is how you're supposed to use it. You're more or less attempting to do the equivalent of `if (fifi instanceof rover)` which just doesn't make sense. How can one dog be 'an instance' of another? It's not that the answer is 'true' or 'false', but that the very question doesn't even make sense, which is why javac doesn't compile it. It has no idea what this even means.

Java, being java, makes objects of many things. Notably including the very notion of things. Thus, there is the class `java.lang.Class`, instances of which *represent classes*. A bit of alice-going-down-the-rabbit-hole thing is happening here: Classes as a concept are *also* represented as instances of the `java.lang.Class` class.

A class OBJECT (so, an instance of `java.lang.Class`) has the `.isAssignableFrom` method. This in fact takes another `j.l.CLass` as argument, it's for checking if one type is a subtype of another. In that sense, the question linked is needlessly confusing - you're really looking for the instanceOf **method** (there is an `instanceof` language construct, but the `j.l.Class` class has an `isInstance` method, which is unrelated, other than that they roughly accomplish the same goal: Check if some INSTANCE is of a type that is equal to, or a subtype of, some TYPE.

This is an example of how to use it:

```
Class<?> c = Number.class;
Object o = Integer.valueOf(5);
System.out.println(c.isInstance(o));
```

this is more or less equivalent to:

```
Object o = Integer.valueOf(5);
System.out.println(o instanceof Number);
```

Except now the `Number` part no longer needs to be written at 'write the code' time, you can supply it, say, read it from a parameter. You'd have to, of course, dynamically construct the Class instance. You can do so either by string-lookup, or by getting the actual type of an actual object. For example:

```
String input = scanner.next(); // user types in "java.lang.Number"
Class<?> c = Class.forName(input);
Object o = Integer.valueOf(5);
System.out.println(c.isInstance(o));
```

Or:

```
Object i = Integer.valueOf(5);
Object d = Double.valueOf(10);
Class<?> c = i.getClass(); // will be java.lang.Integer.class
System.out.println(c.isInstance(d)); // false
```

But doing this latter bit is really dangerous. Often `i.getClass()` returns some hidden impl detail subtype (java is hierarchical and object oriented, anywhere, say, an ArrayList is needed, someone is free to make a new class: `class MyVariantOfArrayList extends ArrayList`, and use that - now you write `ArrayList foo = getList()`, but `foo.getClass()` doesn't return ArrayList - no, you invoke that method **on the object the `foo` variable points at**, so, it'd be `MyVariantOfArrayList.class`, not `ArrayList.class`.

It's possible `Packable` itself represents a type. But then it either needs to also have `isInstance` and `isAssignableFrom` and such (and you need to start questioning why you're badly reinventing the wheel here - java.lang.Class already exists!), or it needs a `.getRepresentedClass()` method. You can't call it `.getClass()`, as the JVM has already given all objects that method, and it would return `Packable.class` itself.

Comment: Thanks for your really in depth comment, it’s helped explain a lot in an easy to digest manner! I’ll try and change my approach to the problem :)