# Determine if an InetSocketAddress is IPv6 or IPv4

Tags: java

I need to determine if an `InetSocketAddress` is IPv6 or IPv4 efficiently. The only two ways I can see of doing this are either using the **`instanceof`** operator, or checking the length of `getAddress()` (which should return a `byte[]`). Both of these are less than ideal (`instanceof` is slow, and `getAddress` would have to make a copy of the array).

Is there a better alternative?

Comment: According [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103564/the-performance-impact-of-using-instanceof-in-java), `instanceof` may not be as slow as you think. Personally, unless you've profiled your app and it's reporting instanceof as taking > 5% of your run time, then I would put off optimizing away `instanceof` for later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think that you will find anything faster than `instanceof`.  In this particular case, I'd expect the JIT compiler to optimize it to loading and comparing a pair of pointers; i.e. roughly 5 machine instructions.

But even if `instanceof` is significantly slower than I understand it to be, it is highly unlikely that it will have a significant impact on your application's overall performance.

I suggest that you just use `instanceof` and only bother to optimize it if you have *hard evidence* of a bottleneck at this point; e.g. evidence from profiling your application on a realistic workload<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1 - Once you have done that, it should be a simple matter to run / rerun your benchmark with two or more versions of the IPv4 vs IPv6 test and *measure* which is faster.</sup>

Comment: i.e. (inetSocketAddress.getAddress() instanceof Inet6Address)

Answer (score 6):

A faster solution is to compare types.  The types Inet4Address and Inet6Address are final, therefore they cannot be subclassed.

```
Inet4Address.class == IPtoCheck.getClass();
Inet6Address.class == IPtoCheck.getClass();
```

Testing shows that this is more than twice as fast as instanceof and isn't affected by the type being compared, whereas the performance of instanceof on Inet4 and Inet6 addresses is different.

Comment: But according to [**this** testing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26514984/139985) `instanceof` is fastest in Java 8.  I am inclined to believe a benchmark whose source code can be reviewed than one that is not cited.  The performance difference is too small to be significant, so my guess is that the Java 8 JIT compiler optimizes  the approaches using `getClass` and `instanceof` to equivalent native code.  Note that the JIT compiler can also determine that a class is a leaf class even if it is not `final`.  And it can reoptimize if a loading another class changes that determination.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like `instanceof`, you could try:

```
Inet4Address.class.isAssignableFrom(IPtoCheck);
Inet6Address.class.isAssignableFrom(IPtoCheck);
```

I don't think there is a faster solution than `instanceof` or the above.

Comment: That will be slower that `instanceof`.  The JIT compiler isn't able to optimize reflective type checking.

Answer (score 1):

Compared to the overhead of constructing the InetAddress itself with its implicit DNS overheads the overheads if any of `instanceof` are trivial.