# java optimization nitpick: is it faster to cast something and let it throw exception than calling instanceof to check before cast?

Tags: java, optimization, casting, instanceof

Before anyone says anything I'm asking this out of curiosity only; I'm not planning to do any premature optimization based off of this answer.

My question is about speed in using reflection and casting.  The standard saying is 'reflection is slow'.  My question is what part exactly is slow, and why; particularly in comparing if something is a parent of another instance.

I'm pretty confident that just comparing the class of an object to another Class object is about as fast as any comparison, presumably just doing direct comparison of singleton objects that are already stored int he Object's state; but what if one class is a parent of the other?

I usually think of `instanceof` as being about as fast as regular class checking, but today I thought about it and it seems that some reflection has to happen 'under the scenes' for `instanceof` to work.  I checked online and found a few places where someone said `instanceof` is slow; presumably due to reflection required to compare the parent of an object?

This lead to the next question, what about just casting.  If I cast something as an object it's not I get a `ClassCastException`.  But this doesn't happen if a cast an object to a parent of itself. Essentially I'm doing an `instanceof` call, or logic to that effect, when I do the cast at run time am I not?  I've never heard anyone hint that casting an object could be slow before.  Admittedly not all casts are to a parent of the provided object, but plenty of casts *are* to parent classes.  Yet never has anyone hinted at all that this could be slow.

So which is it. Is `instanceof` really not that slow?  Are both `instanceof` and casting to parent class kind of slow?  or is there some reason a cast can be done faster then an `instanceof` call?

Comment: If it matters, benchmark. If not, well, ...

Comment: it would depend on the probability that the object is an instance of the appropriate class.  If the probability is high, then exceptions would be faster.  If the probability is 1, then exceptions would be a no-brainer.  If the probability is 0, then you should consider another strategy altogether.  In between, you need to benchmark.

Comment: @emory I had thought that would be true, but see my profiling results, even if you're 99% sure that it is the approriate class it still ends up being no faster to use exceptions. And if you're not 99% sure its much much slower

Comment: @Richtea interesting ... thus if the probability is 0 you should be doing something else; (0,0.99] don't use exceptions, .99 your call, (.99,1.00] use exceptions.

Comment: @emory well: thus if the probability is 0 you should be doing something else; (0,0.99] don't use exceptions, (.99,1.00] your call, [1.00] don't do anything, its 1.00. Exceptions are never better, sometimes they're as good, but rarely

Comment: Regarding the close vote; while this example was for a theoretical situation I myself have considered doing this, tried it and found it to be a bad idea. I expect many people have done the same. If I had the appropriate privileges I would vote to reopen.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As always try it and see in your particular situations, but:

-Exceptions are expensive, remarkably so.

-Using exceptions for code flow is almost always a bad idea

Edit:
Ok I was interested so I wrote a quick test system

```
public class Test{

    public Test(){
        B b=new B();
        C c=new C();


        for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){
            testUsingInstanceOf(b);
            testUsingInstanceOf(c);
            testUsingException(b);
            testUsingException(c);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Test test=new Test();

    }

    public static boolean testUsingInstanceOf(A possiblyB){
        if (possiblyB instanceof B){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    public static boolean testUsingException(A possiblyB){
        try{
            B b=(B)possiblyB;
            return true;
        }catch(Exception e){
            return false;
        }
    }


    private class A{

    }
    private class B extends A{

    }
    private class C extends A{

    }        
}
```

Profile results:

```
by InstanceOf: 4.43 ms
by Exception: 79.4 ms
```

as I say, remarkably expensive

And even when its always going to be a B (simulating when you're 99% sure its B you just need to be sure its still no faster:

Profile results when always B:

```
by InstanceOf: 4.48 ms
by Exception: 4.51 ms
```

Comment: So by our two profile results there is no circumstance where allowing exceptions to be thrown and catching them would be faster

Comment: hmm, interesting, but there is one other situation that wasn't tested in this example.  What if you don't catch the exception; instead intentinoally letting it propigate up to another method designed to handle bizzar runtime exceptions (say by reverting a transaction)?  I'm not saying I want to do that; just that I'm curious and always try to find edge casses lol.

Comment: Ok, I've tried that, exception based test changed to casting and just returning true (no catch and return false block). One try catch block right at the top of the program that never catches anything because its ALWAYS class B. Using Exception (or lack thereof):4.19ms, using instanceOf:4.18. So best case senario, they're the same

Comment: This answer may be old, because the timings don't jive with my tests.  See code in my answer below, it shows that try/catch is not significantly slower than instanceof when the exception is thrown 33% of the time

Answer (score 9):

There is a general answer and a particular answer.

### General case

```
if (/* guard against exception */) {
    /* do something that would throw an exception */
} else {
    /* recover */
}

// versus

try {
   /* do something that would throw an exception */
} catch (TheException ex) {
   /* recover */
}
```

It is a fact that creating/throwing/catching an exception is expensive.  And they are likely to be significantly more expensive than doing the test.  However, that doesn't mean that the "test first" version is always faster.  This is because in the "test first" version, the tests may actually be performed: first time in the `if`, and second time in the code that *would* throw the exception.

When you take that into account, it is clear that if the cost of the (extra) test is large enough and the relative frequency of exceptions is small enough, "test first" will actually be slower.  For example, in:

```
if (file.exists() && file.isReadable()) {
    is = new FileInputStream(file);
} else {
    System.err.println("missing file");
}
```

versus

```
try {
    is = new FileInputStream(file);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.err.println("missing file");
}
```

the "test first" approach performs 2 extra system calls, and system calls are expensive.  If the "missing file" scenario is also unusual ....

The second confounding factor is that the most recent HotSpot JIT compilers do some significant optimization of exceptions.  In particular, if the JIT compiler can figure out that the state of the exception object is not used, it *may* turn the exception create/throw/catch into a simple jump instruction.

### The specific case of `instanceof`

In this case we are most likely comparing these two:

```
if (o instanceof Foo) {
    Foo f = (Foo) o;
    /* ... */
} 

// versus

try {
    Foo f = (Foo) o;
} catch (ClassCastException ex) {
   /* */
}
```

Here a second optimization occurs.  An `instanceof` followed by a `type cast` is a common pattern.   A HotSpot JIT compiler can often eliminate the dynamic type check that is performed by the type cast ... since this is repeating a test that just succeeded.  When you factor this in, it the "test first" version cannot be slower than the "exception" version ... even if the latter is optimized to a jump.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, Richard's code can't be run directly to produce timings.  I've modified the question slightly, assuming that you really want "if A is a B, do something on B", rather than just asking the question "is A a B?".  Here is the test code.

UPDATED FROM ORIGINAL
It was rather challenging to write trivial code that the HotSpot compiler didn't reduce to nothing, but I think the following is good:

```
package net.redpoint.utils;
public class Scratch {
    public long counter = 0;
    public class A { 
        public void inc() { counter++; } 
    }
    public class B extends A { 
        public void inc() { counter++; } 
    }
    public class C extends A {
        public void inc() { counter++; } 
    } 
    public A[] a = new A[3];
    public void test() {
        a[0] = new A();
        a[1] = new B();
        a[2] = new C();
        int iter = 100000000;
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        for(int i = iter; i > 0; i--) {
            testUsingInstanceOf(a[i%3]);
        }
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("instanceof: " + iter / ((end - start) / 1000000000.0) + " per second");

        start = System.nanoTime();
        for(int i = iter; i > 0; i--) {
            testUsingException(a[i%3]);
        }
        end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("try{}: " + iter / ((end - start) / 1000000000.0) + " per second");

        start = System.nanoTime();
        for(int i = iter; i > 0; i--) {
            testUsingClassName(a[i%3]);
        }
        end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("classname: " + iter / ((end - start) / 1000000000.0) + " per second");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scratch s = new Scratch();
        s.test();
    }

    public void testUsingInstanceOf(A possiblyB){
        if (possiblyB instanceof B){
            ((B)possiblyB).inc();
        }
    }

    public void testUsingException(A possiblyB){
        try{
            ((B)possiblyB).inc();
        } catch(Exception e){
        }
    }

    public void testUsingClassName(A possiblyB){
        if (possiblyB.getClass().getName().equals("net.redpoint.utils.Scratch$B")){
            ((B)possiblyB).inc();
        }
    }
}
```

The resulting output:

```
instanceof: 4.573174070960945E8 per second
try{}: 3.926650051387284E8 per second
classname: 7.689439655530204E7 per second
```

Test was performed using Oracle JRE7 SE on Windows 8 x64, with Intel i7 sandy bridge CPU.

Comment: Poor benchmark. It's hard to properly examine the performance of this as branch prediction is likely kicking in. Also who knows that the JIT is jit'ing; JMH or Caliper would be a good choice to redo this in.

Comment: It is indeed hard to bench this without knowing the mix of cases encountered in real world.  However, I've at least tried to mitigate last-branch-taken prediction by rotating through the three cases.    If you have a better benchmark, please post it.

Comment: This is good test, that somehow I missed your posting way back when I asked the question.  I toyed with marking this as the correct answer, since I feel it's asking the optimization question that you usually need to know; but it seems odd to change an answer 2 years old now.  Let me at least give a rather belated thank you for the answer, sorry I somehow missed it originally :)

Comment: Thanks.  My reply was over a year after your post.  I decided to pile on because I needed to know, because the original answer wasn't directly testable (it didn't actually produce timings), and because the JVM performance profile has changed so much over time.

Answer (score 1):

If the cast can throw an exception, it means that it's doing implicitly what `instanceof` would do. So, in both cases you are implicitly using reflection, probably in exactly the same way.

The difference is that if the result of `instanceof` comes back `false`, no more reflection is happening. If a cast fails and an exception is thrown, you'll have unrolling of the execution stack and, quite possibly, more reflection (for the runtime to determine the correct `catch` block, based on whether the thrown exception object is an instance of the type to be caught).

The above logic tells me that an `instanceof` check should be faster. Of course, benchmarking for your particular case would give you the definitive answer.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think you would find one being clearly better than the other.

For `instanceof`, the work done use memory and cpu time. Creating a exception use memory and cpu time also. Which use less of each, only a well done benchmark would give you that answer.

Coding-wise, I would prefer to see a `instanceof` rather than casting and having to manage exceptions.

Comment: Throwing exceptions is quite clearly slower. Especially as the cast is doing an implicit `instanceof` anyways