# Checking a grid, throwing out of bounds exceptions

Tags: java, arrays, exception

Currently, I'm trying to check a grid cells for data in all cells around it. Up, left, down, right, and all diagonals. How can I use exception throwing so I don't have to individually code the sides and corners?

This is currently what I have. isIsAlive() simply checks to see if the cell is "active". Neighbors for a cell include all active cells around it.

```
    public void calcNeighbors() throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException{

    int x =0;

    int y =0;
    int neighbors = 0;



    while(x < 9){
        while(y < 9){

            if(generation[x+1][y+1].isIsAlive()){
                neighbors++;

            }
             if(generation[x+1][y].isIsAlive()){
                neighbors++;
            }
              if(generation[x+1][y-1].isIsAlive()){
                neighbors++;
            }
               if(generation[x][y-1].isIsAlive()){
                neighbors++;
            }
                if(generation[x-1][y-1].isIsAlive()){
                neighbors++;
            }
                 if(generation[x-1][y].isIsAlive()){
                neighbors++;
            }
                 if(generation[x-1][y+1].isIsAlive()){
                neighbors++;
            }
                 if(generation[x][y+1].isIsAlive()){
                neighbors++;
            }
            y++;
        }
        x++;
        neighbors = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer is: don't.  Don't use exceptions for non-exceptional control flow.

Comment: This is a similar code flow through expections question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16320014/java-optimization-nitpick-is-it-faster-to-cast-something-and-let-it-throw-excep/16320082#16320082 In addition to the usual readability problems I did some tests as to efficiency.  It makes for grim reading. The "too long didnt read" is exceptions were 20 times slower than an instanceof (which is itself quite slow)

Comment: On general advice; using "9" is a magic number; **bad**. What if the array size changes,  use array.length. you can get the second dimension with array[0].length.

Comment: You're using loads of near identical if statements; somewhat bad. Use two nested for statements each going between -1 and 1 (with a continue where both are 0). This avoids copy and paste code reuse and makes your logic easier to rewrite later if it changes (and saves you writing loads of boring ifs)

Comment: You're simulating a for loop using a while. Why are you doing that? It makes the code difficult to read and may have lead to a bug in your code because y isnt reset to 0 every time through the x loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't throw your own exception if the hypothetical neighbor would be out of bounds.  Java would throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` anyway.

You need to check your bounds before you access the array; don't access the array if either your `x` or `y` is out of range.

Comment: +1 And importantly, when checking "out of range", don't use magic numbers in the code (e.g., `9`), use the actual array length. (*Even though* in a very gross N/NE/E/SE/S/SW/W/NW grid, there can only be nine -- wait, isn't it 8? -- neighbors.)

Comment: So I can't, say... let the error happen, throw it, and then let it do nothing? Also, it's a 10x10 grid. That's why the array is 9 long.

Comment: @Xenorosth: You *can*, you just *shouldn't*. Exceptions are for *exceptional* conditions, and throwing them isn't free.

Comment: @Xenorosh Can you do it; yes. Should you; hell no. Apart from making the code difficult to read (the main problem) its also devastatingly inefficient

Comment: You _can_ let the error happen and do nothing, but it's a bad idea to rely on exception handling to handle your program's flow control.  This is not supposed to be an exceptional condition.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm not quite sure about efficiency yet as much as trying to solve it. This is for college, so my logic abilities aren't at peak. Computer Science is a very, very hard major. :( I suppose I'll figure out the long way since it seems to be the best.

Answer (score 4):

Your list of if blocks is ugly (to be blunt) and dangerous. Instead use nested for loops but calculate the upper and lower bounds of the for loops taking the edges into consideration.

```
for (int x = 0; x < MAX_X; x++) {
  for (int y = 0; y < MAX_Y; y++) {

    int minRow = Math.max(0, x - 1);
    int maxRow = Math.min(MAX_X - 1, x + 1);
    int minCol = Math.max(0, y - 1);
    int maxCol = Math.min(MAX_Y - 1, y + 1);

    for (int row = minRow; row <= maxRow; row++) {
      for (int col = minCol; col <= maxCol; col++) {
         if (row != x || col != y) {
           if(generation[row][col].isIsAlive()){
             neighbors[x, y]++;
           }
         }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: the fundamental problem is that he's not letting Java do the hard lifting for him since all he needs to use is the most basic logic to test that he does not go beyond the limits. It's the **inner** two for loops in my example above that I'm discussing, not the outer for/while loops.

Comment: Yes, but those loops weren't there when I commented. Re the edit: Doesn't that double-count things?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: no, I don't think so. I've used this sort of code myself with my game of life program and with my minesweeper program.

Comment: Ah, with the edit (`neighbors[x, y]++`), it's not double-counting anymore (and it was a definitions thing whether it did or didn't anyway). (The OP's code did, so fair enough if yours did too, but you've addressed it for them.)

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommended to use exceptions for this purpose.  But if you insist, you could do it in the following way.  First, define a method

```
public boolean isAlive(int x,int y) {
    try {
        return this.generation[x][y].isIsAlive() ;
    } catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
        return false ;    //  Or whatever you want to be the default
    }
}
```

And then use `isAlive(x+1,y+1)` instead of `generation[x+1][y+1].isIsAlive()` and so on.

Additionally, my impression is that you are mistakenly declaring a local variable `int neighbors = 0;`.  I say this because you keep setting it to `0` at the end, but you don't store it anywhere.  Personally, I would define a field `neighbors` in whatever is the base class of `generation` and:

```
for(int x= 0 ; x < generation.length ; x++ ) {
    for(int y= 0 ; y < generation[x].length ; y++ ) {
        generation[x][y].neighbors= 0 ;
        for(int dx= -1 ; dx <= 1 ; dx++ ) {
            for(int dy= -1 ; dy <= 1 ; dy++ ) {
              if( ! ( dx == 0 && dy == 0 ) && isAlive(x+dx,y+dx) ) {
                  generation[x][y].neighbors++;
              }
        }
    }
}
```

My concern with so many `if`s are 3:
 1.  It's very easy to make a mistake.
 2.  It will be time consuming (and error-prone) to add any other code inside all `if`s.
 3.  The logic is easier to understand.  Though you could also add a comment explaining that you are going to check neighbors, and that neighbors are all 8 cells where row or column is +1 or -1 the current cell.

Also, now that we have reduced the number of `if`s, we could also inline the function above and write the following:

```
for(int x= 0 ; x < generation.length ; x++ ) {
    for(int y= 0 ; y < generation[x].length ; y++ ) {
        generation[x][y].neighbors= 0 ;
        for(int dx= -1 ; dx <= 1 ; dx++ ) {
            for(int dy= -1 ; dy <= 1 ; dy++ ) {
                try {
                    if( ! ( dx == 0 && dy == 0 ) && isAlive(x+dx,y+dx) ) {
                        generation[x][y].neighbors++;
                    }
                } catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
                    //  Do whatever you want in this case
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, **without** abusing exceptions (which is by far the most recommended), I'd say add a function

```
public boolean isValidNeighbor(int i,int j) {
    return 0 <= i && i < generation.length && 0 <= j && j < generation[i].length ;
}
```

And your code becomes:

```
for(int x= 0 ; x < generation.length ; x++ ) {
    for(int y= 0 ; y < generation[x].length ; y++ ) {
        generation[x][y].neighbors= 0 ;
        for(int dx= -1 ; dx <= 1 ; dx++ ) {
            for(int dy= -1 ; dy <= 1 ; dy++ ) {
                if( ! ( dx == 0 && dy == 0 ) && isValidNeighbor(x+dx,y+dx) && isAlive(x+dx,y+dx) ) {
                    generation[x][y].neighbors++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Much, much better.  And, even if not the main reason, less code and complexity than with exceptions!!!