# Java generic type's inferring

Tags: java, generics

I have class structure like this:

```
class A1,A2,..,An extends A;
class B1,B2,..,Bn extends B;
```

And class that converts `Ai` into `Bi`:

```
    private B1 convert(A1 a1){}
...
    private Bn convert(An an){}
```

How can I define single public method with signature like `<? extends B> convert(<? extends A> a)`?
Now I have only this approach:

```
    B convert(A a){
      if(A.getClass().equals(A1.class)){
         return convert((A1)a);
      }...
    }
```

Can I use instanceof if perfomance is important and the method will be called frequently?

Comment: Just a thought: IMHO a more elegant solution will be to declare a method in `A` [preferably abstract, if `A` is abstract]: `public B toB()`, that will create a `B` instance from the caller.

Comment: Is as nice as simply! Thank you! Why I didn't think about it?

Comment: Since it seems to help you, I added it as an answer with a code snap. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more elegant solution will probably be to declare a method in `A`: [preferably `abstract`, if `A` is `abstract`]:

```
public abstract B toB();
```

Overriding classes (A1,A2,...) will have to override it and instantiate their own `B` object.

Code snap [the `static` modifier is used since I implemented it as an inner class, it is not needed and cannot be used if the classes are outer classes]:

```
public abstract static class A { 
    public abstract B toB();
}
public static class A1 extends A {
    @Override
    public B1 toB() {
        return new B1();
    } 

}

public static class B {

}
public static class B1 extends B { 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like:

```
public <AType extends A, BType extends B> BType convert(AType a) {...
```

But your could have converter interface like:

```
public interface Converter<AType extends A, BType extends B> {

    AType convert(BType b);

    BType convert(AType a);

}
```

Regarding the performance question, you could take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/103600/1001027)