# How is instanceof implemented in modern JVM implementations?

Tags: java, jvm, implementation, instanceof

Due to the benchmarking done in other threads (cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/397617/1408611) it was shown that instanceof in Java 6 is actually quite fast. How is this achieved?

I know that for single inheritance, the fastest idea is having some nested interval encoding where each class maintains a [low,high] interval and an instanceof is simply an interval inclusion test, i.e. 2 integer comparisons. But how is it made for interfaces (as interval inclusion only works for single inheritance)? And how is class loading handled? Loading new subclasses means that a lot of intervals have to be adjusted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK each class knows all the classes it extends and interfaces it implements. These could be stored in a hash set giving O(1) lookup time.

When code often takes the same branch, the cost can be almost eliminated as the CPU can execute the code in the branch before it has determined whether it should take the branch making the cost next to nothing.

As the micro-benchmark was performed 4 years ago, I expect the latest CPUs and JVMs to be much faster.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    Object[] doubles = new Object[100000];
    Arrays.fill(doubles, 0.0);
    doubles[100] = null;
    doubles[1000] = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        testSameClass(doubles);
        testSuperClass(doubles);
        testInterface(doubles);
    }
}

private static int testSameClass(Object[] doubles) {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    int count = 0;
    for (Object d : doubles) {
        if (d instanceof Double)
            count++;
    }
    long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.printf("instanceof Double took an average of %.1f ns%n", 1.0 * time / doubles.length);
    return count;
}

private static int testSuperClass(Object[] doubles) {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    int count = 0;
    for (Object d : doubles) {
        if (d instanceof Number)
            count++;
    }
    long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.printf("instanceof Number took an average of %.1f ns%n", 1.0 * time / doubles.length);
    return count;
}

private static int testInterface(Object[] doubles) {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    int count = 0;
    for (Object d : doubles) {
        if (d instanceof Serializable)
            count++;
    }
    long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.printf("instanceof Serializable took an average of %.1f ns%n", 1.0 * time / doubles.length);
    return count;
}
```

finally prints

```
instanceof Double took an average of 1.3 ns
instanceof Number took an average of 1.3 ns
instanceof Serializable took an average of 1.3 ns
```

if I change the "doubles" with

```
    for(int i=0;i<doubles.length;i+=2)
        doubles[i] = "";
```

I get

```
instanceof Double took an average of 1.3 ns
instanceof Number took an average of 1.6 ns
instanceof Serializable took an average of 2.2 ns
```

Note: If I change

```
if (d instanceof Double)
```

to

```
if (d != null && d.getClass() == Double.class)
```

the performance was the same.

Comment: I was also thinking about this hashtable approach. But it seems that instanceof is in some situations even faster than a hashtable lookup could be. It was even faster than a single function call without parameters.

Comment: The generated code can be inlined. For the case of `Double` above, as the class is `final` the test is the same as `d != null && d.getClass() == Double.class`