# How to iterate only over specific kind of elements?

Tags: java, oop

I have an array list as such:

```
private List<GameObject> gameObjects = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<GameObject>();
```

`GameObject` can be one of 3 classes: `Spaceship`, `Beam` and `Asteroid`. They all are similar so I keep them in one array. However spaceships have addition method shoot which is used every 100ms in other thread (which is called `ShootRunnable`). So I would like to iterate in it only over `Spaceship` because other doesnt implement shoot method. What is the best way to achieve this?

```
for (GameObject ob : gameObjects) {
  if (ob instanceof Spaceship) {
    ob.shoot();
  }
}
```

Can I iterate over it using something like the above? Just with the use of a cast or something? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

The path you're on is technically feasible, though a good rule of thumb is that if you start using reflection, you're probably doing something wrong.  In this case, it might be wisest to have a two collections, one for all your game types, and one specifically for spaceships.

Comment: That's what I thought about too. But then every action connected with spaceship I will have to do twice. So when I add new spaceship I will have to add it both to gameObjects list and spaceships? And when remove, remove it both from gameObjects and spaceships. :/ But you think its the best way?

Comment: Correct.  Don't worry, computers are fast. :)

Comment: Ok so that's how I will do. Thanks a lot

Comment: Although instanceof is not cheap, maintaining 2 collections is crazy idea. Better to use instanceof

Comment: How wrong is this approach?
Create your own class implementing the List interface and create another list inside that class called spList. Override the add(E e) and remove(Object o) methods of the interface to add and remove a ref to/from the spList if the object is an instanceof Spaceship.

Comment: @archer What if the long iterations are costly? Would there be any better alternative besides instanceof?

Comment: Charlie gave me the reference to this thread with benchmark results: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103564/the-performance-impact-of-using-instanceof-in-java

Comment: I agree that the use of instanceof (or every other type comparison) might be a sign of something wrong in your design. However, the adoption of two different collections is an overkill. Polymorphism is the key: I would suggest to encapsulate the behavior that triggers the object action into the object itself as suggested in the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

In your game, are there any other actions that happen periodically?

If so, you could change the `shoot()` method into an abstract method (could be named `periodicAction()`) and place it in the `GameObject` class. The `Spaceship` class would implement this method by shooting, the other class with its specific periodic behavior and the `Asteroid` class by doing nothing.

Comment: adds unnecessary complexity

Comment: @archer: no it does not. It is a common practice on game development to add an update/step/tick/think function on every entity in the game.    Take the doom 3 code of the idEntity as example (line 172): https://github.com/id-Software/DOOM-3/blob/master/neo/game/Entity.h

Answer (score 0):

You should put your shoot() method into the Spaceship class beacause no asteriod or beam will use this method. Done this, you should also keep at least two collections. One of them should only contain your spaceships.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather do this way:

```
 Iterator<Spaceship> getSpaceships(){
     // return Iterator over Spaceship objects through use of instanceof
 }

 ...
 Iterator<Spaceship> it = getSpaceships()
 while(iter.hasNext()) it.next().shoot()
```

To me it looks more clear.

Comment: "Anytime you find yourself writing code of the form 'if the object is of type T1, then do something, but if it's of type T2, then do something else,' slap yourself." --Scott Meyers, Effective C++

Comment: that's not mine design man ;) I'm just trying to suggest a feasible soution

Comment: but you suggest the use of instanceof, only hidden inside an iterator

Comment: there's no better way. read comments on other answers and you will decide the same. instanceof actually is not that expencive and this is a `natural` way to get class type information without the need to maintain separate enum or list. I've proposed that way only to separate instanceof comparision with call to `.shoot()` which (IMHO) is better to do on objects which are already separated into another list/set/iterator

Answer (score 0):

You could create an interface `Action` or a method into `GameObject`:

```
public interface Action {
   void performAction();
}

public abstract class GameObject implements Action {
   //...
   public void performAction() {
      // subclasses should override this method.
      // otherwise, it will do nothing.
   }
}
```

and then, implement `Spaceship`:

```
public class Spaceship extends GameObject {
    @Override
    public void performAction() {
        this.shoot();
    }
}
```

To `Beam` and `Asteroid`, you can leave the method `performAction`:

Then, you can interate over:

```
for (GameObject ob : gameObjects) {
  ob.performAction();
}
```