# Java 2D Game Polymorphism

Tags: java, polymorphism, game-engine

I am developing a simple 2D game in Java and I'm stuck.

All my game objects(`Enemy`, `Player`, `Item`, `Wall`, ...) are extending `Entity`.

`Entity` is an abstract class containing some abstract methods like `update()`.

I have made an interface called `Drawable` which contains a `draw()` method.

Some game objects like `Item` should be an `Entity` but also be `Drawable` while others, like Wall, should just be an `Entity` (not connected to a tile, just x and y coordinates)

It all looks something like this:

```
List<Entity> entities;
```

In constructor i do this:

```
entities = tileMapReader.getEntities();
```

My question is: How should i draw my `Drawable`s?

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
for (Entity entity : entities) {
    entity.draw(g);
}
```

But since all Entities don't have the `draw()` method I can't do that. And i don't think `if (entity instanceof Drawable)` is such a good idea.

Comment: What you usually do is that the model classes don't know anything about being drawn. Instead, you have some GUI classes that are the ones that contain your model classes and knows how to draw them. That way you can also reuse all the code in case you want to show your game in different devices, for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep an additional collection of Drawables. That way you can limit to drawing those, and do all the other things to all Entities.

Comment: Hello and thanks for answering! I thought of this as well but isn't there any other easier way? Maybe it's just me being lazy.

Comment: It doesn't need to be difficult, if you make some sort of automation so that any time you create a Drawable, it's also added to a list of Drawables.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds smart and efficient!

Answer (score 1):

You can test whether an `Entity` implements `Drawable` using the `instanceof` operator:

```
for (Entity entity : entities) {
    if (entity instanceof Drawable) {
        ((Drawable) entity).draw(g);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I wrote this in my question but is it really effective to have in your game-loop?

Comment: @OscarLinde - The performance hit from using `instanceof` is probably insignificant, even in the game loop. See, for instance, [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103564/the-performance-impact-of-using-instanceof-in-java). Also, it's likely that the drawing itself is much more expensive than `instanceof`. If you have just a few `Drawable` objects in a vast sea of non-`Drawable` `Entity` objects, then [Kayaman's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21814808/535871) would be a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

First, your walls are invisible? Second, I like the other two answers: You can either keep a collection of Drawables, or check to see if that one implements Drawable.

A third option would be to have all entities implement drawable and leave the Wall's implementation blank.

Comment: I'm loading a tile map and i have invisible "objects" in a seperate layer. These objects determine whether i have collided somewhere or not. They don't neccesarily have to be the size of the tile they're on, and are therefore invisible.