# usage of instanceof vs adding isSomething() to base-class

Tags: java, reflection, instanceof

Say I have this class hierarchy:

```
Animal <-- FourLegged <-- Dog
Animal <-- FourLegged <-- ....

Animal <-- ThreeLegged <-- ... (what has 3 legs?)

Animal <-- TwoLegged <-- Chicken
Animal <-- TwoLegged <-- ...
```

(Forgot what the scientific terms for four-legged and two-legged animals are. But that's beside point, right? :) )

If I have an `Animal` object, and I need to know whether it is a `FourLegged` or if it is a `TwoLegged`, I would normally do `animalObject instanceof FourLegged`.

**Is that slower than adding a bunch of `isFourLegged()`, `isThreeLegged()`, `isTwoLegged()`, to `Animal` class?**

**(I would like to know the performance impact. This is NOT a design exercise. So I would appreciate it if you won't be wasting time suggesting how to re-write the class)**

**Edit**
Some people have suggested adding 'getNumberOfLegs()", which is perfectly reasonably given this specific example. But suppose the point is NOT to have the number of legs, but to get what type of animal this is.

Comment: How about `getNumberOfLegs()`?

Comment: Yeah, I almost knew someone would suggest this. :) (I happened to give myself  an example that would raise this.) But no, suppose the point is to know what type of animal this is. Not how many legs

Comment: try `animal.getClass()==FourLegged.class` same for others

Comment: I thing asking object of its type violates Liskov Substitution Principle, so maybe you can think of a better way of handling your problem, like the one with `getNumberOfLegs()`

Comment: @Braj No, that won't work for subclasses of `FourLegged`, etc.

Comment: @ChuckB `Class#isAssignableFrom()` will work in that case.

Answer (score 1):

If your subclasses doesn't add any behavior and is just a way to specify the number of legs, you should go with [this refactoring](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-subclass-with-fields) called **Replace Subclass With Fields**. => no need for subclasses any more.

Otherwise, add a polymorphic method like: `numberOfLegs()`, implemented by each of your `Animal`'s subclasses.

Comment: Ok, I appreciate you taking time to answer my question. But I don't believe this actually responds to my question which is whether "instanceof" is slower.

Comment: With any good computer nowadays, instanceof is really not a problem. If you look at some advised refactoring made by Martin Fowler, you will notice that slowness isn't a true issue in 99% of cases. He doesn't hesitate to make a same loop twice or more, if the code could be really cleaner, for instance.

Comment: @OneTwoThree Look at the selected answer of this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103564/the-performance-impact-of-using-instanceof-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    Animal animal = new Dog();

    if(animal.getClass().isAssignableFrom(FourLegged.class)){
        System.out.println("FourLegged");
    }
```

Do it in same way for others

Comment: Reflection and any similar stuff are the enemies of good design ;) IMO

Comment: Does `Class#isAssignableFrom()` use reflection?

Comment: it's just a "similar stuff" :) Essence of OO is:  "I don't want to be forced to check before calling".

Comment: Ok, I appreciate you taking time to answer my question. But I don't believe this actually responds to my question which is whether "instanceof" is slower.

Comment: @Mik378 `isAssignableFrom`and `instanceof` really don't count--and your statement is too broad in any case. (Perhaps non-framework code should generally avoid reflection.)

Comment: @Mik378 can you share me any link where it's defined that `Class#isAssignableFrom()` uses reflection.

Comment: @Braj I didn't mean that isAssignableFrom is reflection. I just include this kind of stuff as being a "meta-data" (like reflection is) and any good design should avoid if possible.

Comment: @Braj When you write this: `animal.getClass().isAssignableFrom(FourLegged.class)`, you make your code really tied to the code structure. It'd be better to don't have any knowledge of the existence of the `FourLegged` class in the referential of the caller. Loose coupling is preferred in any cases.

Answer (score 0):

The question centers around the "speed" of execution: Is one way slower than another?

Unless you're talking about algorithmic differences, the only way to know anything remotely accurate about performance is to **measure** your expected use case.  In Java many variables affect performance, including the JVM chosen, JVM arguments, and so on.

Having said that, it is straightforward to see that `instanceof` potentially has more work to do:

1. Set checkClass = this.getClass()
2. Is checkClass == the target class?  If yes, return true.
3. Does checkClass have a superclass?  If no, return false.
4. Set checkClass = superclass of checkClass
5. Goto 2

(With potentially more effort involving the possibility of interfaces; in this case I am presuming that the JVM implementation is aware that the target class is not an interface and can use that knowledge to its benefit.)

However, a virtual method call requires no potential iteration: Fetch a function pointer from the object's vtable, and call it.

But when the target class is the immediate superclass of the object, then there is only one iteration in traversing the class  hierarchy. Is that case "faster" or "slower" than a virtual method call?

Bottom line:  It depends.  When performance matters, **measure**.  In the absence of data clearly pointing to a performance bottleneck with the code, prefer code that is clear, concise, understandable, and maintainable.