# Is this an acceptable use of instanceof?

Tags: java, oop, instanceof

I am working on an implementation of the card game UNO (mostly to run simulations to test some house rules, but that's a different story).

For those who've never played it, it's similar to Crazy Eights.  Players take turns playing a card on the discard pile.  The card has to match in number or color.  There are also draw cards, which force the next player to draw either two or four cards.  It's also quite friendly to house rules, which makes it pretty interesting.

I have a `Card` class with the `value` and `color` of the card.  What I would like to do is to create `DrawCard` which extends `Card`.  Then, in determining the game mechanics, I would use `instanceof` to test whether I have a `DrawCard`.

I know that `instanceof` is often problematic, but this seems to be okay to me.  Usually the cards are processed the same, and only a few special cards are treated differently, and only in specialized circumstances specific to the card type (That seems like a slippery-slope thing to say though...)

I could just use markers in the `Card` class (actually, each type of card already has its own 'value'), but I am extending `Card` anyway in order to have some methods that other types of cards may have (it's not just a means of identification).  Using `instanceof` seems more general to me, as I wouldn't need to know about which values of `value` require this special behaviour, and it would be easy, for example, to add a Draw 8 card to the current contents of Draw 2 and Draw 4.  (Saying this makes me wonder if I could use some sort of nested enum or something, but I don't know)

I know that both solutions would work (make the program run).  To me using `instanceof` feels nicer, but I don't have the experience to understand whether it is okay.  Is this bad design?

Comment: you my find the answers on this post helpful: [The performance impact of using instanceof in Java][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103564/the-performance-impact-of-using-instanceof-in-java

Comment: Does the "draw" card (not the class) also have value **and** color? If not, then inheritance is not the proper solution here -- inheritance is a "is a" relationship. Note that, if the "draw" cards do have values or colors, they must have the exact same semantics for them to be considered.

Comment: @acdcjunior Yes, draw cards have colors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer: Not really acceptable, so yes - it's a sign of a design deficiency. `instanceof` is almost always a smell except in rare cases where a library is trying to do some kind of assistance that is meta or otherwise ugly but helps overcome a language/environment shortcoming.

With that opinion, the question is sort of a duplicate. See the answer to:

[When is it acceptable to use instanceof?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749271/when-is-it-acceptable-to-use-instanceof?rq=1)

It suggests to use the visitor pattern. This may be true if you genuinely have two different types in the system.

You also don't have to use the visitor pattern 'explicitly' but rather incorporate it in to your program flow. So consider an interface card:

```
interface Card {
  void pick(Player player);
}

class DrawCard implements Card {
  void pick(Player player) {
    player.draw(value); // assume value passed in e.g. ctor
  }
}
```

Comment: OK This makes sense.  The way my game is currently set up, the game control class passes the card to the player's play method.  So I could put methods in the Card interface to determine properties of the card? Something like a "does the next player to see this card have to draw" boolean method?

Comment: That's fine, I would just have the player, in response to being given a card, then 'pick' the card (you can rename it to `onTaken` or something like that if it makes more sense), but then have the card implementations call methods on the player to continue the turn. This might mean adding points to the player (player.increaseScore) or telling the player they have to do more things (player.takeMoreCards).

Answer (score 0):

I would say in general it's best to avoid `instanceof` wherever possible.

While it's somewhat vague since you didn't post any actual code, one option in this type of situation would be to implement two different *interfaces*, say `ICard` and `IDrawCard` and have the `Card` class implement the `ICard` interface and the `DrawCard` class implement both *interfaces*.

Then you would be able to differentiate the `DrawCard` class by virtue of its *interface* in function signatures, etc. (that is, refer to it as an object of *type* `IDrawCard`).

**Edit in response to comment from OP:**

In terms of handling the action after the card is played, you can leverage the interfaces to *override* the function that handles the actions. Since that's the context for this, I would probably recommend three different interfaces:

1. `ICommonCard`
2. `ICard`
3. `IDrawCard`

Where `ICommonCard` is the generic interface for when you need that which perhaps handles has some general-purpose methods, and the other two interfaces handle the needs of those two specific types.

Then say you have an action handler method named `handleAction`, which could be defined thusly:

```
void handleAction(ICard card)
{
    // do ICard stuff here
    return;
}

void handleAction(IDrawCard card)
{
    // do IDrawCard stuff here
    return;
}
```

And then when you call that function, you can pass off an object which is the type of the interface into the overloaded function (one option would be to have a member variable for each type, and if it's going to be one or the other, pass the one that isn't `null` into the function).

Comment: Thanks, I probably should use interfaces.  How does this change using instanceof to identify them, though?

Comment: Well, it really depends on exactly what you're trying to do. As I said above, you can refer to them by their interface in function signatures, etc. so that can help to differentiate. What's the context, specifically?

Comment: The cards have different behaviours, like what happens after the card is played.  I need to know what the type of the card is so I can determine what is a valid action after it is played given the last card played.