# Scala - Run-time performance of TypeTags, ClassTags and WeakTypeTags

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-reflect

**Introduction**:

> ... `TypeTag[T]` encapsulates the runtime type representation of some compile-time type `T`. ...
>   ... `TypeTag`s are always generated by the compiler. ... [[1]](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html)

`TypeTag`s are located in [`scala.reflect.**`](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs-master/library/index.html#scala.reflect.package) packages. 
Another [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/435568/3041008) mentions that using java reflection will incur a run-time performance overhead in your application.

**Question**:
To what extent do `TypeTag`s, `ClassTag`s and `WeakTypeTag`s use java reflection at run-time? They are generated at compile time, but do they cause a run-time performance overhead when used?

**Example**:

```
def isOfType[A : ClassTag : TypeTag, E : ClassTag : TypeTag](actual: A, expected: E): Boolean = {
  actual match {
    case _ : E if typeOf[A] =:= typeOf[E] => true
    case _ => false
  }
}

assert( isOfType(List.empty[Int], List.empty[Int]))
assert(!isOfType(List.empty[String], List.empty[Int]))
```

Although the tags are generated at compile-time, I can *feel* the delay when running it. Do the type comparisons use the not-so-performant java reflection under the hood?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can look [here](https://github.com/scala/scala/tree/2.11.x/src/reflect/scala/reflect). In your case Java reflection is not involved, but `=:=` eventually delegates to [`isSameType2`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/5e0880fe05fb65a8757721be7e5be6a3259c19a8/src/reflect/scala/reflect/internal/tpe/TypeComparers.scala#L182), which is quite non-trivial. It does check reference equality first.

Comment: So would you say the type comparison's overhead is negligible in this case or would you suggest avoiding it where possible? (I am aware that this is somewhat subjective, and only micro-benchmarking can give correct insight).    
What about the match expression `case _ : E`? AfaIk `ClassTag` comparisons are involved here, are they also done without java reflection?

Comment: It depends (shocking, I know). It definitely isn't always negligible, since it's one of bottlenecks in our own project. In `case _: E` Java reflection _is_ involved, but you shouldn't fall into the trap of thinking all reflection is slow and all code without reflection is fast; in particular `isInstanceOf` is very fast, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/397617/9204