# How can instanceof be faster than a polymorphic call?

Tags: java, jvm

I was looking at the answers of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103564/the-performance-impact-of-using-instanceof-in-java).

How can it be possible that `instanceof` has turned out faster than a polymorphic call like `equals`.

Comment: You mean the long and detailed answer with the Gist code and graphs? Everything is possible in a botched microbenchmark, which that answer is an instance of.

Comment: you already have your answer in the link you are just using equals instead of == rest same as linked question , explore the all answers in the link

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: no, that long and detailed answer does not make such a claim. I suppose, this question refers to the second most (undeservedly) upvoted question, which compares two entirely unrelated operations (string equality check and `instanceof` operator).

Comment: @Holger I believe we are both referring to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26514984/1103872). It's the second-most upvoted one and the only one with graphs and Gist'ed code. But i don't see string equality there; i see `.class` compared with `==`, an `else-if` cascade with `instanceof` and a `switch` with `type`. It's broken in many ways.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: seems, I can’t count to three anymore. No, I assume, this question referes to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/397617/2711488) which indeed compares `instanceof` with `String.equals`… The other answer can also be considered questionable regarding its benchmark methodology, etc., but it makes more sense than comparing `instanceof` with `String.equals`…

Comment: @Holger Both the answer and the discussion below it is such total nonsense that explaining what is wrong with it would take longer than writing a new answer from scratch.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: most answers there are crap. What I like about the answer with the graphics is, that the bars look so random, that it’s even possible to draw the correct conclusion from it. Unfortunately, nobody did…

Comment: @Holger Given that the measurement loop _always_ involves a `switch` statement that decides what to instantiate, the results are truly meaningless.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: yeah, and the most expensive operation of every iteration is the use of the `Random`, which is also the only thing that can’t be optimized away, as it’s initialization advances a global `seedUniquifier`.

Comment: @Holger Yes, it's the old-school thread-safe, high-overhead `Random`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose, you are referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/397617/2711488) which should be downvoted to the ground instead of getting so much upvotes. First of all, any numbers posted without showing the actual code under test nor naming any benchmarking tool should be considered to be a (perhaps) interesting comment rather than a quality answer.

Second, this answer compares two entirely unrelated operations, a `String` equality check and the `instanceof` operator. That answer misleads the reader (like you) into thinking that it bears any finding about the cost of Java’s method dispatch, but there is no way to measure that cost in isolation. If you measure the cost of invoking a method doing *work X* (like String comparison), you’re basically measuring the costs of *work X* (the String comparison), rather than the invocation cost. Since `instanceof` doesn’t perform a String comparison, it’s obvious that it does less work than calling `String.equals`. Especially, as the implementation of `String.equals(Object)` even does an `instanceof` on the argument.

So it should not surprise you when calling `String.equals` imposes more costs than doing a sole `instanceof` operation, giving an answer to an entirely different question. The linked answer still is not sufficient to prove that this actually did happen. Measuring 80±17ms and 168±62ms for a loop of 10,000,000 iterations is a clear sign that the actual costs of the loop body are buried deep under statistical noise.

Besides all that, `String.equals` can not even considered a polymorphic call.