# What JIT do with instanceOf operator?

Tags: java, jit

I've read this link [The performance impact of using instanceof in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103564/the-performance-impact-of-using-instanceof-in-java?noredirect=1&lq=1]), this is its citation:

> Modern JVM/JIC compilers have removed the performance hit of most of the traditionally "slow" operations, including instanceof, exception handling, reflection, etc.

I'm wondering what JIT does with `instanceOf` operator. Is there any detail explanation. Thank you so much!

Comment: It's really hard to give a detailed explanation of why that statement is true, without going way more in-depth than an SO question usually can (in other words: this could be a book). Basically the JVM can often optimize away assumptions that always (or almost always) hold by having a fast-path that only works in those cases and going to a very slow code path when it doesn't. And very often that very slow code path never gets used.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: Thank you, at least I have an overview of it. I'll be better later on.