# Subscribe design pattern

Tags: java

I have an interface called `Dog`, by default this "dog" is spawned for all players in the game i'm making, so I have extended this interface and created a new one called `PerPlayerDog` that basically spawn different "dogs" depending on player, for this I have added a method called `spawn(Player)`. I also have a registry class that stores all the dogs, so I iterate over all the `spawned dogs` and i check if the dog is `instanceof PerPlayerDog` and then I spawn this dog using my own logic, basically only for players that are nearby in a X radius all this in a repeated task that runs every second to check for the players to spawn the dog for, the problem is that using `instance of` for more than "100+" spawned dogs and every second is expensive and not optimized, so I wanted to know a better option, also maybe it is better to rename the class to `SubscribedDog`?, and have methods to subscribe to this dog for a player is this correct?, tell me your ideas or how i can improve the code, thanks.

```
interface Dog {
    String getDogName();
    UUID getUUID();
    
    DogModel getDogModel();
}


interface PerPlayerDog extends Dog {
    void spawn(Player player);

    /** players that the dog has already been spawned for */
    Iterable<Player> getReceipts();
}
```

Comment: Do you need to assign the one "dog" for all nearest players?

Comment: @VolodyaLombrozo what?

Comment: Could you explain more clearly (with examples) the use case with  "repeated task" for spawning dogs?

Comment: still need help!!

Comment: "*the problem is that using instance of for more than "100+" spawned dogs and every second is expensive*". No, it's not.

Comment: @Michael https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103564/the-performance-impact-of-using-instanceof-in-java

Comment: @Profeta Thanks. It says it takes 2 nanoseconds. x100 = 200 nanoseconds. Absolutely nothing.

Comment: @Michael yes still, if there are more dogs it will take more, and there are better workarounds for this problem and not use instanceof at all

Comment: Write code that you think is easy to read. Solve performance problems that you can actually perceive and measure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Question

It's hard to suggest to you something particular because the right solution depends on business logic a lot. Someday the current chosen solution will have to be changed when the requirements change. We can't know your environment and circumstances and your question should be more [clarified and more focused](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

In any case, I can offer you a few simple options:

---

### Add the `spawn` method to the `Dog` interface

First of all, you can add the `spawn` method for `Dog` interface directly:

```java
public interface Dog {
    String getDogName();
    UUID getUUID();
    DogModel getDogModel();
    void spawn(Player player);
}
```

Then you can just ignore `spawn` for some dogs:

```java
public class IgnoredDog implements Dog{
    @Override
    public void spawn(final Player ignore) {}
    
    //other methods 
}
```

Or implement logic for another dogs :

```java
public class PerPlayerDog implements Dog{
    @Override
    public void spawn(final Player player) {
       if(player.getDistance(getDogModel().getLocation()) < 5){
           //todo
       }
    }

    //other methods
}
```

Your task in this case:

```java
@Override
public void run() {
    for (Dog dog : dogRegistry.getDogs()) {
        for (Player player : players) {
            dog.spawn(player);
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Change the `DogRegistry`

You can change `DogRegistry` method  `List<Dog> getDogs();` - to the next: `List<PerPlayerDog> getDogs();`, or you can add another method `List<PerPlayerDog> getPlayersDogs()` to `DogRegistry`.

Your task in this case:

```java
@Override
public void run() {
    for (Dog dog : dogRegistry.getPlayersDogs()) {
        for (Player player : players) {
            dog.spawn(player);
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can create another Registry and store `PerPlayerDog` list separately.